# When is the recalculation update?

Tags: discussion, questions, reputation, upvotes

When is the recalculation update listed below?

https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/

Comment: Presumably as we speak

Comment: I'll do you one better: who is the recalculation update?

Comment: We're working on it.

Comment: Over the next two days.

Comment: Retroactively recalculating reputation is just a huge break of trust. This should not be happening, ever.

Comment: I'll do _you_ one better: Why is the recalculation update?

Comment: Hmm so, a decision got made to make a vote on a question a +10 instead of +5, which led to this recalculation process. Yet do those that made the decision actually know _why_ a question upvote is not equally worth as an answer upvote? I advise try to spend a week answering newest questions first. Those statistics does not show the actual content. You only see numbers with it.

Comment: @KarelG  The recalculation is so that a vote on a answer or a question are both the same at  +10.   It was a change in 2011 that made them different.

Comment: @Karel The blog post is unfortunately very light on meaningful details. To answer your question, please read [this answer of mine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/391248), where I explain the historical background and the justification behind the change.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Effectively, "now". Other than that, there is no precise timeline for completion.

The recalculation has already been performed on Meta Stack Exchange. The team responsible for such things is busy working on performing the recalculation for all sites in the network, including Stack Overflow:

> [We're working on it.
>
> –Taryn](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391245/when-is-the-recalculation-update#comment739858_391245)

You'll see the changes roll out slowly across the network, taking into account the substantial load that a recalculation of this magnitude places on the database servers.

---

Nick Craver of Stack Overflow has been [live Tweeting the recalc process](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver), which he has spent the day supervising, along with Adam Lear, Taryn, and other team members.

[Step 1](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/1194710851493793792): Kicking off a recalculation of reputation across the entire Stack Exchange network using their "state-of-the-art developer UI".

> [image]

[Step 2](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/1194717314182197251): Biting the bullet and kicking off the reputation recalculation for all 2.57 million Stack Overflow users.

[Step 3](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/1194719400349306880): Watching SQL Server put some sweet server hardware through its paces.

> [image]

[Step 4](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/1194781092462649344): It's all over but the crying.

> Reputation recalcs have finished network-wide, but our event queue has piled up a bit (about 9.2 million events pending) as a result. It make take a few hours for all events to flush out naturally:
>
> [image]