# Upvotes on questions will now be worth the same as upvotes on answers

Tags: discussion, reputation, upvotes, announcement

Those of you who suffer from [banner blindness](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/banner-blindness-old-and-new-findings/) may not have noticed the announcement:

[**Stack Overflow is changing the reputation scoring system to make the reputation earned from upvotes on *questions* equal to the reputation earned from upvotes on *answers*.**](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/) Previously, upvotes on questions netted you only +5 reputation, whereas upvotes on answers netted you +10 reputation. Now, upvotes on posts will always be worth +10 reputation, regardless of whether that post is a question or an answer.

This change will not only take effect for contributions from here forward, but it will also be applied *retroactively*. A global reputation recalculation is pending and will be completed soon. Note that this recalculation *will* take the daily reputation cap into account. (The Mortarboard, Epic, Legendary, and Yearling badges will also be awarded, as they would have been earned under the new logic, but they are awarded nightly by a separate, background process, and thus may not show up at the same time as your recalculated reputation.)

The net effect will be to reward the contributions of users who have asked well-received questions, in recognition of the fact that useful, high-quality questions are just as valuable as high-quality answers. Asking a good question is difficult, takes practice, and is a meaningful contribution to the community at large, critical to our mission of building a high-quality library of questions and answers to practical programming problems.

No other changes are being made to the reputation system. Receiving downvotes on one of your questions will still reduce your reputation by the same amount as before. [Casting downvotes on questions is still "free"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90324/should-downvotes-on-questions-be-free), in the sense that it does not reduce the reputation of the voter.

**Why?** You can find [more detailed background information in my answer here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/391248), including a review of the history and an assessment of the facts that justify this change.

The biggest immediate change will be a substantial increase in user reputation scores, and thus an increase in the number of users having [certain privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges).

As with far too many events of late, this change has been accompanied by a fair amount of drama. The proposed policy modifications were privately announced to community moderators by staff members some time back. Unfortunately, a less-than-ethical member of the larger Stack Exchange moderator community leaked this private communication to the public, and did so in a rather sensationalist way. I want to commend the Stack Exchange employees both for soliciting feedback from moderators and for *listening* to that feedback. I would ask that the community focus on the facts of the announcement and the policy as it has actually been implemented.

To that end, if you have questions, concerns, comments, or other feedback about this change, please post it as an answer here. You can also express your sentiments silently by voting. As always, we ask that you keep your feedback constructive and respectful. Feedback from those who cannot comply with this requirement is subject to removal.

Comment: We already have newbies complaining about these simple questions with hundreds of upvotes. Not very welcoming to double the score of these, forcing the poor new stackoverflowers to work even harder to catch up!

Comment: At this point I'm more and more surprised that we still come to SO. This might not last long, though. I feel so betrayed...

Comment: Not that I actually care but, since the score was 10 then got lowered to 5 and now back up to 10 again. What happens to those points earned 2007-2010 that was worth 10, will they be 15 when this recalculation is done?

Comment: @Patrice The score for questions won't be doubling. Just the reputation gained by the askers because of the upvotes. The score will remain the same. The only real change is that there will be more users with more reputation. Some privileges (such as upvoting), will be awarded much sooner, which I guess can in turn can feed into this mechanic as well...

Comment: I actually agree with this. Perhaps not the retroactive. But then again why should they not be same values as new upvotes. I find it way harder to write a question than a answer. And usually answers get far more upvotes than questions that can take up to hours to write good. A simple 5 min answer can get more points than it actually should in just a few minutes.

Comment: My fervent opposition to this change has nothing to do with the fact that I have only ever asked one question on SO.

Comment: So valuing *"lack of knowledge"* the same as *"actual knowledge"* seemed like a good idea? I don't really care about the changes, but seems more like the goal is to get more questions, and so more content, not necessarily more **good** content in the form of good answers? This surely will benefit some of the top users, that early on have asked and answered their own questions on basic issues, with thousands of upvotes over the years.

Comment: @adeneo A knowledge base cannot exist without high-quality questions to solicit good answers. The reputation system isn't valuing knowledge at all. Rather, it is valuing your *contributions* to the Stack Overflow knowledge base (and thus serves as an indirect proxy for your familiarity and experience with this platform). The fundamental thought behind this policy is that good questions are a net positive contribution to the Stack Overflow knowledge base. Content that is not good can and should continue to be signaled by downvotes, whether questions or answers.

Comment: @CodyGray - A fool can ask more questions than a wise man can answer, and at the end of the day SE still needs people that actually knows the answers to the questions, more than they do fools. My opinion is that answers should be valued higher than questions, and downvotes should count the same as upvotes, but what do I know, I've never really asked a single question?

Comment: Most of my reputation has come from question asking so far. But honestly I think the 5/10 split was fair: it's harder and less gratifying to write an answer, and the question-asker usually has some real-world benefit to getting their question answered as well. Questions definitely have a lot of value, but I think answers have even more value. This is not a horrible change, but I'm a little unsure whether it's the right one. Have there not been enough high-quality questions?

Comment: "Those of you who suffer from banner blindness may not have noticed the announcement:" - we had to dismiss it several times, so no worries there. And then there's that leak thing.

Comment: It appears that someone (Mage Xy) as already created a [SEDE Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1148217/estimated-rep-bump-from-question-upvote-change) to show the reputation change for a user

Comment: My only complaint with this is the reputation losses/gains in the top bar on Stackoverflow has not been showing changes; I have seen my rep change in the last few hours, but haven't been able to see the source unless a comment is also left (or I go digging). TLDR: The realtime rep change notifications aren't working currently. Edit: Just had an answer accepted, don't see the `+15`

Comment: It would be interesting to see how much rep people are getting from this at the top end.

Comment: *"The net effect will be to reward the contributions of **everyone, including users who have bad questions that still exist on the site**"*. Fixed that for you.

Comment: @wim Recalculations always take the daily 200-cap into account. It's a re-calculation taking the entire history into account, not just "count question upvotes, multiply by 5, add to current reputation". It's the same recalculation that happens e.g. if old votes are removed because of deleted users - believe me, I've tried often enough to circumvent the cap :-)

Comment: Don’t look now, @Herohtar, but even if we all just sat around doing nothing, there would be users being rewarded for posting bad content. That’s an unfortunate side-effect of an imperfect content rating system. Some people will upvote any darn thing; some people never downvote. The real solution to the problem you highlight is not fiddling with the rep weights. It’s *downvoting* and *removing* the content that doesn’t meet our quality standards. Easier said than done, of course. But gonna need to be done no matter what we do about points.

Comment: Please don't blame users for not downvoting when downvoting is a privilege that you have to unlock and costs more rep than upvoting.

Comment: @CodyGray The problem is, people *don't* downvote -- or even vote to close -- in cases where they should, and it seems to happen even less with all the recent push to be "nice". And people hand out upvotes just to "counter" a negative score on a question, which with this rep change rewards the poster even more than it previously did.

Comment: But some of us only post answers and didn't just have our rep doubled, so we don't yet have close vote privileges, and now the relative weight of our downvotes just got cut in half...

Comment: @Herohtar "in cases where they should" is a subjective statement and it makes it seem like a moral judgement when it isn't. **The platform actively discourages downvoting** by making it **cost rep to downvote answers** - to say that users should downvote and is doing wrong by not downvoting is extremely insincere, when the platform itself gives the message that you rarely ever should.

Comment: @Unihedron I'm talking about questions, not answers, and as stated in the post above, [downvoting questions is free](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90324/should-downvotes-on-questions-be-free). Additionally, voting to close does not have any negative cost. There are pretty clear guidelines on what constitutes a well-asked question, so at the very least, there should be little question about whether to vote to close something.

Comment: While that they are functionally distinct, they are 1. both unlocked at 125 rep, 2. presented with the advice to ["use them wisely" and "should be reserved for extreme cases"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) neither of which is a light tone, and as I'd reiterate from before, **discourages it outright**. as if it's not enough, the buttons look the same, and 3. clicking on either will deliver the same "don't click this" message that pops up. Voting to close does have a cost, as close votes are not finite, you're using up 2% of your VTC battery a day.

Comment: I just cannot figure out how can anyone that has spent more than five minutes moderating this site come to the conclusion that increasing reputation for the questions will actually result with more quality questions being asked. I am genuinely baffled.

Comment: The rationale behind this change seems a bit shallow. Maybe we could get more than one or two euphemisms from the decision making process?

Comment: More questions = more page views. More important now than curating good answers. I fear stackexchange is swirling the bowl thanks to a radically different vision being forced down by the CORP. If you still care about your ranking, and you concentrate on giving good answers, consider this the same as cutting the value of all your answers in half.

Comment: Wow, some nerve asking us to ignore the fact that another decision was made with limited feedback from the larger community feedback and having the nerve to ask us to ignore the drama.  Your priorities are out of whack.

Comment: This should coincide with a reinstatement of the 3 close votes closes/holds a question. And, make that *retroactive*; just close those questions outright. All the accounts using sock puppets (whose rep has possibly doubled today) might lose much of that undeserved rep SO has doled out.

Comment: @jmoerdyk Sorry, I will try and revise the phrasing on that. I'm not asking you to ignore other events that have actually taken place. Although that would be ideal, I realize it is not realistic and perhaps not even sensible. I was intending merely to talk about the "leaked" versions of this proposal that are circulating around on the Internet, with some dubious information.

Comment: @mario Everyone seems to be missing it, but I have provided a "meaty" justification for the change [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/391248/366904), and linked to that in the question above. I had originally intended to provide that explanation as part of this question/announcement, but zero298 scooped me in asking his question first.

Comment: @CodyGray I'm sure you're caught in the middle of things here, but I couldn't help but notice who authored the blog introducing this change.  It seems like SO in general is trying to continue on like it's business as usual with a blitz of blog posts and podcasts.  There are much more important topics that need to be addressed and not swept under the rug, most importantly the breach of trust recent events have created.

Comment: @CodyGray TBH, I still can't wrap my head around it. If the previous +5 has only advantaged the persistent low quality posters, then how is +10 going to benefit the few who spend more effort (but with fewer questions)? Is the rep change by itself going to encourage the right user base? Is the Q+A rep equality going to change voting preferences enough? (I still feel this needs more elaboration, less focus on new users.)

Comment: @jmoerdyk Isn't that the whole point? Sweeping it under the rug until everyone forgets?

Comment: With so many questions showing no minimal effort and simply asking yet still getting upvotes, this is rather an unneeded change.

Comment: As someone who rarely comments on meta, but has read much of what has been happening, I just wish you'd asked the opinions of the user community (and not just the moderators) before rolling out the change, given how everyone feels right now... People who are downvoting may even have warmed up to the idea. You say that the change was made because data suggested it: it would have been nice to be able to see this data, and why it justifies the change. I like to think we're a community that can change our opinions when presented with evidence to the contrary.

Comment: Now my hard-earned reputation point from answering seems to worth less than it used to be... :)

Comment: We seem to be incredibly worried about keeping a newb, and not retaining people who answer

Comment: _I want to commend the Stack Exchange employees both for soliciting feedback from moderators and for listening to that feedback._ Does that mean that the proposed change was even worse?

Comment: When I though that SO was about to stop doing bad changes and just stand still, you guys never stop surprising me!

Comment: Wow, @wim, that is an impressive, but also disappointing (selfish) statistic. 1,186 questions, and only 1 answer. One would hope that someone with that many questions had contributed to others more than once at least.

Comment: @Larnu - why selfish?  Maybe they are learning.  Maybe their questions have helped others searching.  Maybe they are not confident enough of their skills to post answers.

Comment: Provided answers is also a great way of learning, @user1725145 , and you try to solve problems that aren't your own. Only ever asking questions (over a 1,000 of them), to me, would suggest the OP is only concerned on their own problems. Yes, those questions have definitely helped others, but after 1,000+ questions you would expect someone to be competent enough to answer questions as well :)

Comment: @Larnu your opinion.  Not everyone is as confident as perhaps you assume them to be (eg may not have good communication skills).  Also, if their own problems are someone else's problems, then that's good enough, they've shared something useful.  As an aside, I don't like this change, which looks like a blatant attempt to raise the falling post numbers, but hey, codidact when all's said and done (wonder how long this comment will last...)

Comment: I went down from 29xx to 33xx in the ranking because I answer a lot but barely ask. Totally unfair, should apply to new questions only

Comment: "OK, we succeeded in getting the more annoying mods and users to resign, but what about the remaining high-rep users who insist on downvoting and closing, so hitting ad stats?  They're mostly highly skilled and experienced developers who are,politically aware'' ... "Hey!  I know how we can really piss them off while looking good - we can't take their rep, but we can devalue it!"

Comment: @CodyGray - Am I right in thinking that you created this post on your own merit? I only ask because my current feeling is that any feedback received here is going to be ignored by Team Podcast. Kudos to you if this is true though!

Comment: *"...high-quality questions are just as valuable as high-quality answers..."*. Yes, but *low-quality questions are **more** valuable than low-quality answers* unless you lower the person's rep on down-votes. In fact, one could argue that *overall, questions are more valuable than answers* with this change. And to think, I've been coming here all these years for answers, not questions.

Comment: @CodyGray If there was a "Jumped on the Grenade" badge you should get one.

Comment: @Herohtar yes, and as one of those people who used to upvote somewhat poor but salvageable questions as an encouragement (esp. when they got a lot of downvotes as you say) I will now actively go through all my upvotes and undo those that I find I did like that. I've already started doing it. The change to the rep system causes me to re-evaluate my voting preferences. And since they did it retroactively it only seems fair for me to redo my votes retroactively as well.

Comment: @Sayse: To be fair, Team Podcast has *always* been detached from the actual content or events of the site(s) (all the way back to 2008). The first series had a little bit, but not very much - [boat](http://web.archive.org/web/20100426125115/http://www.mattmcdole.com/boat/) [programming](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/) (hard deleted on Stack Overflow) and [Spolsky's LOGO one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003841) come to mind.

Comment: @WillNess You weren't really using upvotes correctly if you were applying them based on "this user should earn 5 rep but not 10 rep for this".

Comment: @TDG: Only the association bonus is given by the system itself. There is on-going inflation in the system, whether question upvotes are valued at +5 or +10, depending on how you look at it (worsened by voting rings and *deliberate* posting of low-quality questions (that get upvotes))

Comment: 83.1% of unanswered questions last week and still believing that such a tragedy for a Q&A site can be mitigated by increasing the number of questions rewarding those who ask with "reputation". Obviously, the strategy behind this decision is purely commercial and confirms that StackOverlow has long ceased to be THE site to seek technical answers. Many results on Google but very few really useful. I have never asked a question and I stopped answering them years ago. I still check the site for interesting answers, more scarce every day unfortunately.

Comment: It's part of being more inclusive. Actual knowledge is secondary.

Comment: I've just seen one (vampire) account go from ~2k a few days ago to >20k today (~1.2k questions).  How is that possible?  I would have expected it to double, not go 10 fold!  At least we know that bumping rep does actually work! Doubling the answer rep score would create mod powers for those users that actually care about the site, rather than users that only want answers to their questions IMO. This is another disappointing announcement

Comment: Not sure if you're aware but opening your post with "Those of you who suffer from banner blindness may not have noticed the announcement" does not harbor good will. Aside from the obvious trudge of Stack Overflow moving away from quality and pushing for quantity why don't you just remove all moderation tools. The influx of crap is already outpacing any crowdsource hours that anyone puts in but then again maybe this is a ploy to propel newbies into these once prestigious designations of moderation given that exoduses keep happening.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I'm not sure how leading with a joke does anything to harm good will. The point is that the policy has already been announced, you've all surely seen it, so this isn't really an announcement. It's a forum for those affected to share their feedback, including criticism. I'm going to skip the giant strawman in your second sentence. There's no evidence SO is moving away from quality, and *I* certainly am not. Yes, the influx of crap is a huge problem. However, reducing rep gain from questions did nothing to address that problem. It is not the ploy you accuse it of being.

Comment: @haldo Exactly what I'd expect for a vampire account -- most crap questions will have several downvotes but a few pity/"me too" upvotes, staying around neutral rep before, but being major rep gains now. For example, a +2/-5 question used to be worth 0 rep, now it's worth +10. Or this question (currently +152/-359), were rep counted on meta, would change from +42 to +802, almost 20x as much.

Comment: Imagine if this same idea was put into a corporate pay structure. Senior people (who know a lot) are paid at some dollar amount because of their knowledge. People with less knowledge (less senior people) are paid less because they _know_ less. As they learn more, they are paid more, in general. This would be like giving all less-senior persons the same pay as senior staff... which is like slapping the senior people in the face e.g. your extra knowledge is worthless.

Comment: @adeneo, do you really call the ability to transform a problem emerging in the code of a real-world project into a minimal, complete and verifiable example "lack of knowledge"? Or there has never been a well educated, expirienced developer, who is suffering from poorly documented API and needs help figuring out the cause of a particular strange behaviour? Furthermore, in a numerous of occasions in the real life I was able to find a mistake made by people with a far more experience than me (call it luck), with them still being superior regarding their understanding of the matter.

Comment: "As with far too many events of late, this change has been accompanied by a fair amount of drama." [Mandatory XKCD](https://xkcd.com/1124/) [Also relevant XKCD](https://www.xkcd.com/592/) Also, that statement is pretty clearly a "subtle put-down," as the CoC terms it.

Comment: @scopchanov - That's not at all what I wrote? The ability to transform a problem into a minimal, complete ...etc example goes for everyone, it's a requirement. My point was, when you ask a question you're lacking knowledge, hence why you ask for help, but when you answer a question, you actually have that knowledge that someone is seeking. Now which one do you think is harder to come by, the people lacking the knowledge, or the people having the knowledge, and which one of those should be awarded the most fake internet points, i.e. who would you consider "most useful" to a Q&A site?

Comment: It's like the SO administration have become convinced that the downvote button is broken and needs to be tested continually... what else could explain the abysmal stream of policy and innovation that seems to fill these pages of late?

Comment: @scopchanov FYI, most questions receiving at least one upvote do not match your description. Most questions are (as nearly as I can deduce from reading them) the result of very little thought or effort.

Comment: @jpmc26, I agree. I am only saying, that asking a question should not be **always** regarded as a _lack of knowledge_.

Comment: @scopchanov I suggest that you are misreading adeneo's original comment as suggesting a *general* lack of knowledge when it instead refers to a lack of *specific* knowledge. If the asker had the knowledge, they would not need to ask. The second comment refers to trends; the **bulk** of questions appear to come from users with a rather large knowledge gap. This was my experience, in fact: as I gained more experience and knowledge, I have nearly ceased asking questions as I've gotten much better at finding answers. I can (and do) still self answer, though, and my questions are better as well.

Comment: @jpmc26, I have read it exactly as it was written.

Comment: Can the SO software at LEAST support some smart filtering of negative-voted questions then?

Comment: I feel like Stack Exchange is trying to divert our attention from Monica-related issues by ruining everything else at this point.

Comment: `Unfortunately, a less-than-ethical member of the larger Stack Exchange moderator community leaked this private communication to the public, and did so in a rather sensationalist way.` I don't know what this is referring to or if it is relevant to the question.

Comment: If you don't know what it's referring to, @Yvette, then feel free to ignore it. Unfortunately, there *are* people who *do* know what it is referring to, and the message is intended for them. (You could become one of these people with a few selected Google keywords, but...don't?) I made a very intentional decision to confront that issue head-on as part of the announcement, which I believe was a good choice, considering I have only seen one comment referring to it, which was promptly deleted. Everyone is doing a fantastic job of staying constructive and on-topic, which I very much appreciate.

Comment: @CodyGray I don't think that that hint is the cause for a constuctive discussion. I think the real reason for a constructive discussion is that you communicate a lot in this topic. It is not a fire and forget announcement like some others here or on MSO lately. You (and others like Yaakov or Shog) understand that communication is the key, even if you can't change the decission your announcement is about.

Comment: I see why they made this into a banner and a blog post, instead of a post in https://meta.stackexchange.com/ : they knew we wouldn't like it, and we can't downvote blog posts into oblivion.

Comment: The karma is not about the worth of your knowledge. You don't get karma because your answer proves that you know a lot. You get karma, because you improve the knowledge base. And asking a well-received question prompts for good answers, what helps to improve the knowledge base. Just stop assuming, that karma is a system to reward your knowledge and prove your self-worth. It is a system to count positive engagement.

Comment: **Up-voting reputation should be in decrease subsequently** and also there should be limit for gaining reputation on any question or answer, by this only old users will not get benefited as usual, it gives change to new users to get more reputation than old users.

Comment: @adeneo I would argue that a wiseman has a lot more questions then answers.

Comment: Now a question needs to get a -5 score to offset just a +1 vote reputation change. This just makes things even easier for the voting fraud rings to game the system.

Comment: Cries "Am a rich maahn now!!" -- after receiving a 1.1K rep bump for some trivial Qs from 10 years ago.

Comment: I thought the site was like a democracy not like a tyranny of a few...

Comment: I find these comments quite troubling. It seems there are those in the community that value the answer as a bargaining chip. All they have are the answers they give and now that exclusive club is being measured against those that ask good questions. I would like to point out that the only reason you get to rise to the top of the point system is because someone else asked the question. They also share in the priviledge of your knowledge. For those talking about 'democracy': yeh but when the site is evidently over-flowing with elitism, maybe democracy is the last thing we need.

Comment: @joshmcode, except this isn't a corporate site. This isn't even a meritocracy, it's a shared community with a flat structure. The points are a trust system, not a paycheck. Also your analogy is incorrect coz Steve Jobs. The man who asked the questions and yet knew precisely f%$k all about computing.

Comment: for talk of "community", I only see answers from high rep users. There is more to the "community" than high rep users

Comment: @Christopher Anyone who wants is free to post an answer containing their feedback. It is not limited to high-rep users. In fact, several answers have been posted by users with small amounts of reputation. There is no conspiracy afoot here. High-rep users are the ones with the most invested in this community. It makes sense that they're the ones who check the site most regularly, have the strongest opinions, and take the time to post answers.

Comment: @CodyGray never talked about a conspiracy. Don't know where that came from. The community includes many more people that are not represented here. And look at the pushback mostly from high-rep users. Why would they post. I remember being a low rep users. What I am telling you is that this page does not represent the community. It represents the view of high rep users. That is vastly different.

Comment: The community includes *everyone*; no one is saying it doesn't. What do you expect should be done about the fact that this page does not include everyone, @Christopher? People post because they have an opinion and they care about the site. That's...kind of the whole point of this question. Apparently you have an opinion, too. Please post an answer.

Comment: @CodyGray this question and most answers **don't** include a representational sample of the community. It represents the high rep users. I'm not saying anyone is saying its not. Just pull a stastical analysis of this page and see. It's not representational. This page should be taken with a grain of salt. I would imagine that the SO team has put in more effort to get a representational understanding of the community than this question has

Comment: @BitShift _"...now that exclusive club is being measured against those that ask good questions."_ Not necessarily good, but highly upvoted. There are a lot of (*)"bad" highly upvoted question here. (*trivial, lazy, no own research etc.)

Comment: @Markus Kauppinen sure, and maybe that's a problem. However now we step into very subjective topic: what is a good question? If the question adds value to the community, then does it matter if it was trivial, or that no self-research had occured? I understand that SO shouldn't be a free for all, but it is still a repository of questions that are highly situation-specific and intended for people to learn without wading through poorly worded library documentation. It just seems that if many SO users had their way, that no questions would ever be asked.

Comment: @BitShift Can't disagree. So I won't. :)

Comment: Ooooh! Participation trophies!

Comment: While the very negative score of this post might make it **seem** the change is not appreciated, the new reputation system is giving the poster a net benefit, so clearly people like this post!

Comment: We have some users who derive practically all their rep from asking lazy questions, and this change doubles their rep. nice move guys.

Comment: @Nathan The solution to that is more downvoting of lazy questions.

Comment: absolutely, I'm trying to do my share of that.

Comment: @CodyGray - Thats true but then its full circle because then we're accused of not being nice

Comment: @Andreas "I find it way harder to write a question than a answer." I thought a bit about it and I would say that it depends. Give me a good answer and I'll need mere seconds to write a question suitable for that answer ("How to do X?", "Why is Y?", "What is the solution to Z?"). It's relatively simple and we do not require that much prior research anymore. However, it usually is the other way around, so coming up with good questions first might be a bit harder. It might be very hard now, where the knowledge base is kind of saturated already. Questions nowadays aren't that useful anymore.

Comment: @CodyGray "The solution to that is more downvoting of lazy questions." I don't think this will happen realistically. If the fix is to have to clean up even more thoroughly, maybe the action was not the right one.

Comment: @ChristopherRucinski "This page should be taken with a grain of salt." Sure. But then SO is already doing that. Since a year or so they regularly get negative feedback. In a way they seem to be very consistent in their actions.

Comment: "Unfortunately, a less-than-ethical member of the larger Stack Exchange moderator community leaked this private communication to the public"... I missed why this was unfortunate. Could you explain why this should've been kept from the public? or is it explained somewhere?

Comment: It was *asked* to be kept private, @eis, so sharing it was a major violation of trust, on the order of the things that we’ve complained about staff doing. Staff and mods were still discussing this, trying to agree on what would be best for our communities, with mods as community representatives. Short-circuiting that discussion before it had been completed makes it difficult to expect to have that opportunity again next time. See also comments [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/391250/upvotes-on-questions-will-now-be-worth-the-same-as-upvotes-on-answers?noredirect=1#comment740070_391276)

Comment: @Trilarion I doubt you can write a **good** question that fast. With good question I mean: no follow up questions, all tags correct, enough examples that it's easy to see what is asked, on or more attempts, it can't be a "duplicate", and that you know what you ask so that it's not a xy question. I always try to make my questions as good as possible but because of that it can take hours or days because as you write the question you start noticing stuff that has not been tried or other ways around it.

Comment: @Andreas "I doubt you can write a good question that fast." I probably depends. Writing good questions in your sense (i.e. no duplicates) was probably much easier in the old days, when SO was young. What I meant is that it's relatively easy to pose a question if a good answer is already existing. Just ask for the answer to the problem that the answer is answering. Just look at all those highly upvoted questions, they are mostly not showing much research, but they are useful to others because they have the same problem.

Comment: @Andreas I kind of think that Q&A is more or less the same like P&S (problem and solution) and since every good solution must already contain the problem it solves in it, it's not so difficult to extract the problem part from the solution and add a question mark after it? Coming up with problems that are worthwhile to solve on your own may be harder though.

Comment: Does anyone at StackOverflow actually _use_ StackOverflow anymore? Or did they all leave?

Comment: Since SO is randomely doing unpopular things, can we also double the value on answers?

Comment: I am very disheartened by this change. Recently I have seen a lot of bad questions that I would downvote (as would others) only to have a single person upvote (because they feel bad) to grant this extremely poorly written question reputation. It sucks. Here are questions from a users who wants to get spoon fed code and provides no meaningful work on their own, only to ultimately gain reputation. And to be honest @CodyGray it is pretty damn apparent that the mods and staff of SO didn't represent the community with this decision, looking at the votes in this thread along with all your comments.

Comment: @CodyGray are the retroactive changes all finished?

Comment: @CodyGray So, I guess you'll just let this stand and ignore that the community is indeed not happy with the changes?

Comment: @CharonX Why would Stack Overflow care whether the community is happy? What they care about is ad views, and Teams subscriptions. Nothing more.

Comment: @user253751 Well, in the short term they might not care, but by alienating core users (i.e. the users that do the grunt work by e.g. **moderating**,  **editing**, **flagging**, and especially **answering**) they hamper the future of the site network (e.g. due to a decrease in question & answer quality) resulting in less traffic, which in turn means less revenue from ad views and subscriptions...

Comment: @CharonX I see you still have not encountered a business.

Comment: I'm afraid this will lead to have an ever growing number of (potentially bad) questions and an ever **diminishing people willing to answer** (there's **way much more effort in answering than in asking**!). To avoid this, why not doubling the answer value accordingly? Or, at least **let the upvoter choose** to vote +5, +10 or even +20 (why not, if it is a really great question?).

Comment: I've been competing for rep with my coworker and he overtook me a while ago but this change catapulted me ahead of him so thank you :)

Comment: @KyleDelaney how did you become aware of the point increase. I dont remember point total at the start of November, but I also don't remember getting a points increase at all. So do you know how much and when you got it?

Comment: @ChristopherRucinski - Since there was no numeric notification like there is for the points you get for new upvotes etc., I have no idea what the actual amount of the increase was. I had just been paying some amount of attention to my score so I knew that I had suddenly gone from far below 4000 to far above 4000. And of course I knew there's no way I could've overtaken my coworker except for a sudden change like this. I see you and I have similar rep so maybe we could compete too :P

Comment: -1 for "Those of you who suffer from banner blindness" - perhaps you should put less banners with useless information if you want people to notice them and not ignore them

Comment: Oh god ... Now, we succeeded in bringing the more annoying mods right on SO :(

Comment: Because of this change, I have 2k rep now, and I can't gain any more rep from editing. I failed to maximize my rep potential

Comment: Next, let's make question downvotes cost the same as answer downvotes and calculate that retroactively as well!

Comment: @clickbait: That's a good and bad news in one package for you. For me, this change makes my rep from my 1k answer is not worthy enough at the face of 100 question user. See https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/823140/top-users-indonesia . I guess I need to make more questions to boost up my rep.

Comment: How stupid is this? I have no problem with SE throwing away 10 points to those "askers". But why don't you just consider awarding like +20 points for the answerers at the same time?

Comment: this makes no sense for reasons stated in many answers below. i will never upvote a question again.

Comment: This question, which currently sits at a net -500 votes (419 up, 919 down), would net the asker about +2.3k reputation (ignoring daily limits), despite it being received obviously not very well. Before, it would have netted just +250 reputation, barely enough to even have to ignore daily limits in my comparison.

Comment: "now" - "soon" - whatever: has the recalculation happened or did someone cause an integer overflow?

Comment: Why so many dislikes? It's a terrible change but why shoot the messenger?

Comment: So "not sure" is now worth the same as "helping people"? Helping people is voluntary whereas a lot of questions are asked by people not knowledgeable about the subject... now if a question gets one upvote and four downvotes the author still nets +2 rep

Comment: @expressjs123 Asking questions is also helping people. That's the whole point of the site. We are building a repository of questions and answers. We cannot succeed at that mission without questions. Good questions have value.

Comment: Good thing we don't allow opinionated questions on the main site, right, @GrumpyCrouton?!

Comment: @CodyGray Maybe I've lost some context to my comment after a year, but I don't see how your comment relates to mine.

Comment: The first thing i thought when seeing this question was "Why is this user's rep above 1? And it' s ridiculously high as well!"

Comment: Why would you expect the user's rep to be 1, @JackJohnson?

Comment: The question got minus 508 point

Comment: Yes, because people disagree with the change, @JackJohnson. That's what downvotes indicate on the Meta site. There is no reputation here, so downvotes don't "cost" anything. (Although I have plenty of upvoted posts, too.)

Comment: well, that's a new thing

Comment: No, it's been that way forever, @JackJohnson.

Comment: what i meant was it was something new for me

Comment: This rule change has created many high rep idiots.  I just encountered another today who, after 12 years on SO, has a 50k reputation built entirely on asking lots of questions, but who answers almost none.  There should at least be a limit on how many reps a user can earn by asking mostly questions.

Answer (score 874):

It looks like the question upvote weight is being doubled, but the downvote weight is not being increased in proportion.

I don't mind the change, but we should be rewarding **good** question askers, not just **any** question askers. Without the downvote weight also increasing, this change is more strongly incentivizing posting poor questions.

Why is the rep cost for having your question *downvoted* not also increasing?

To put things in perspective, a question which is downvoted 4 times and upvoted *once* will still be a net positive for the asker. And if you use Stack Overflow at all, you'll know questions that get downvoted in 4:1 ratio are generally garbage and should not be rewarded at all (they should be edited or closed/deleted).

Comment: Note that the rep cost for having your *answer* downvoted is still far less than the rep gained from having your answer upvoted. Does that policy make sense to you? And, if so, why should questions be any different?

Comment: I also feel we'll be seeing a lot more "poor questions" out there. With this change you only need 1 upvote to balance 4 downvotes. After all you only need to get very few upvotes to make a poor question worthwhile.

Comment: @CodyGray  To be honest, no, it doesn't make sense to me.  If it was my decision to make, the rep cost would be **symmetric** -10/+10 for both questions and answers.

Comment: Looks like we're [optimizing for sand](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/) again

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced that upping the Q-upvote rep will cause more poor questions. My impression is that vampires want to be spoon-fed. They don't care about rep. If someone is posting a question with the intention to farm rep, they're probably invested enough into the site to be less likely to post crap.

Comment: I agree with your overall premise, but if a question gets downvoted 9 times and upvoted once, wouldn't that still put them at a net -8 rep?

Comment: I suspect that question bans are based on upvote/downvote ratio rather than reputation, and that they're more important for keeping askers of bad questions away than reputation.

Comment: isn't it likely that questions that get a downvote:upvote ratio of 4:1 will be deleted and have any reputation removed anyway?

Comment: @JoeW If it's a low-traffic tag, probably won't even get closed (at least, not if the 3 votes to close policy isn't re-instated), to say nothing of deleted in a timely manner...

Comment: This is "by design" result of "be welcoming" policy. So do not expect change.

Comment: [Here is Jeff Atwoods take on increasing the weight of downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/42763/172266). Quote: *Downvotes were always essentially cosmetic, with an extremely minor effect on reputation. Despite this, received downvotes are taken quite seriously by users. Almost too seriously.*.  Indeed, it seems that even if -4/+1 still has a positive reputation effect, it still upsets question askers. Garbage should be closed.

Comment: The perceived impact on reputation goes in the way of asking questions IMO. And a downvote when asking, especially if it looks like it hurts the small rep you have at beginning, can be very painful. Maybe questions should not impact reputation at all.

Comment: I agree with @DenysSéguret, questions shouldn't impact reputation at all. Or at least not be valued as answers as this is comparing apples with pears. IMO there should be seperate counts, one for questions (if at all) and one for answers. Apart from that, the privileges system is problematic as well as it is coupled to reputation. It's about perception which makes it seem unfair. IMO privileges shouldn't be awarded based on reputation but rather earned based on participation and other factors. Leaving reputation for it's original purpose, to underline the quality of the answer / question.

Comment: @CodyGray Questions are how we organize content here; content doesn't show up on threads based on answer score; we have /questions; we don't have /answers. If you want to see answers, you have to filter by them explicitly in search, and even then you don't have any value or context from the answer until you read the question.

Comment: There are so many diamond posts lately that people downvote and disagree with. Doubling the downvote rep loss would make look worse than they already do. With that in mind, I agree that it should be doubled.

Comment: Even with the downvote penalty doubled, this change still benefits the asker. An upvote/downvote pair used to net the asker 3 reputation. Even with your change, it would net them 6. (That's better than netting them 8, of course, but still a change for the worse.)

Comment: @Xrylite Reputation doesn't exist on Meta sites, which is where all the disagreement over site policies happens. Regarding doubling the reputation lost from downvotes, see [this related discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7322/should-the-weight-of-downvotes-be-increased) from several years ago.

Comment: if your question gets a net score of 5 or 10 positive upvotes, then all upvotes count as 10 points, because that's an indicator that you posted a good/useful question. I could get behind such a mechanic.

Comment: @CodyGray Except on the Meta Stack Exchange which is where I'd like to use my downvotes to dissent the most.  But hey, I guess I'll just sit at 99 there forever.

Comment: I disagree.  The best voted questions are simply the most commonly asked questions (no matter how basic and no matter how little effort is needed to find the answer).  There is nothing wrong with this (IMO) and is the reason Stackoverflow is my go-to Q&A source and is really the concept SO was founded upon.  SO didn't get where it is because people asked brilliantly crafted question after first spending 28 weeks researching the issue to avoid downvotes.  It got where it is because it allowed common questions to exist (regardless of quality and solution-effort).  My $.02 (and opinions).

Comment: Using this question as an example, it has now 222 upvotes vs 551 downvotes, netting  -329.  Still, it would have generated 1118 points to the submitter.  This a bad example, as it is on meta where people vote to agree/disagree with the change.  And a question that generated such a divide and attention on non-meta is probably something interesting.  Still an interesting number to consider.

Comment: @cs95 It's funny how, against the current backdrop of SE's newspeak regime, even someone like Jeff Atwood can come across as an alt-right fascist threatening the punks on his lawn.

Comment: Upvote/downvote should be a "zero cost game": downvotes should cancel all positive reputation on the site regardless of their count. So if there are 8 times more upvotes on the site than downvotes, then the ratio should be +10/-80. This means only way to ever have positive reputation is consistently making above average posts. Deleting a post should only hide and don't undo reputation and downvotes should be free to cast in unlimited numbers (as long as it doesn't trip the serial voting protection).

Comment: Because content is King, even substandard content. Double strength upvotes help to keep substandard questions from being automatically hidden.

Comment: Why not a middle-of-the-road approach, and having downvotes affect your rep (severely, 1:1) after 1k rep, but not at all before that? That way newer users can build up basic site-use features (e.g. commenting) without fear of revocation, while higher-rep users (or those wishing to be such) would need to post high-quality answers and questions that deserve upvotes more than downvotes. The privilege for casting downvotes may need to be moved to a different rep point, but other privileges look like they're reasonable for any experienced site user to have.

Comment: What if we allowed users to decide on a range of what their downvote is worth? e.g., someone has a decent question but needs to put more work into it: -2 points. Someone clearly wants someone to to their homework, -10 points.

Comment: One thing I haven't seen mentioned, is that the actual number of up/down votes is a) not visible to lower-rep users, and b) not obvious to the ones who can see it. So if a question stands at zero votes, you don't actually know how many people voted either way... eg. to help close it (if bad, or is that delta votes only?) or balance it either way. And I really have no idea how some of the questions are getting _any_ upvotes at all... it almost seems automatic that a newbie gets their question upvoted even if the first 3 comments on it are "show us an MRE".

Comment: Rewarding **any** question askers? Here's a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59116634/how-to-add-a-new-element-to-a-master-component-in-adobe-xd) that has absolutely nothing to do with programming. It got -1 + 1 - 1 vote, and the user went from 1 reputation to 9.

Comment: I still don't understand the correlation some users are suggesting: that the number of virtual points I get for a question affects the way I compose it. Like "wow, if I get a million points for my question, then let's write it with horrible quality" or what?

Comment: I don't agree that downvotes should be worth the same as upvotes. If a question is objectively bad, then it won't receive any upvotes. If the community is mixed as to whether or not the question is bad (e.g. it's total upvote + downvote is zero), then the question asker deserves the benefit of the doubt that the question is good, and still does deserve to earn some reputation.

Comment: [A recent example of the problem you're describing.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340906/216712) A question with only 96 upvotes out of 430 votes (about 22%) nets the user positive reputation.

Answer (score 703):

I'll ignore the problems of the decision being made behind walls and being contrary to what the community asked.

I'll ignore the fact that what we, as engineers, wanted, was more quality and less noise, not a bigger amount of trivial questions that maintained documentation (or sometimes similar previous questions) would better answer.

I'll address a deeper point of morality.

What made us answer, the promise behind the very word "reputation", which was described as *"earned by convincing your peers that you know what you’re talking about"*, was that those points were a kind of measure of our problem solving ability, of our technical knowledge.

This was the very reason behind the badges, the flair, the gamification.

Even when we gave advice in comments and sometimes answered as CW or in the chat, the meaning of those points was never lost.

Those points weren't the reward for building some SEO tailored content or for making more people look at ads; they were a recognition of our abilities. This was not the whole of it; most of us big answerers are also part of many communities and FOSS projects because we're helpers at heart, but it was a core motivation.

And now, the rule changes. Now reputation seems to be a measure of the traffic we build.

This is why I feel betrayed. Because it's a contract change, it's a depreciation of what made us build SO.

Comment: The change is bad. Pulling it  out of a blackbox, without consulting the user base is worse. But recalculating reputation *retroactively* is a huge break of trust. A falsification of history. Deceit. You can tell I am not happy with this.

Comment: I could not agree more, great answer. Also great point @ErwinBrandstetter.

Comment: I'm not sure reputation was ever really a good measure of your technical expertise.  It can certainly be a *part* of it, but, mostly, reputation is a measure of activity on the site.  Anything at all approaching the standards would, eventually, result in gaining rep.  After you're past the initial threat of the question/answer ban, it's just a function of time spent, more or less.

Comment: @fbueckert no, it was never a *good* measure (which is why I built this: [SkillRep - experiment in computing a skill focused reputation](https://stackapps.com/questions/6520/obsolete-skillrep-experiment-in-computing-a-skill-focused-reputation)). But KPI are only very rarely *good*. It wasn't *so* bad though and was *meant* as a kind of measure as the name proves.

Comment: The harvested reputation points are more a measure of participation than anything else. On the question side, some users have literally asked 1000s of very low quality questions (you know who you are) - essentially pollution. A few questions are downvoted, but the net result is tens of thousands of reputation points.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter While I disagree with the change as well, making a change and *not* re-calculating reputation seems unsound to me.

Comment: @Bergi: Think of bank accounts. If a company decided to re-shuffle wages (without consulting the staff) that would be an outrage (and typically not legal). But if they also recalculated everybody's bank account on this flimsy base, that would just destroy trust, basically deconstructing the money system. If wages change (based on a more reasonable process), past wages are not retroactively recalculated.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter While I agree with you, just a minor point: I don't like the "wage" word because we didn't *work*. We didn't want reputation for the boring skill-less parts like looking at the review queue (we did these boring parts because they had to be made). We wanted reputation for the fun and interesting parts and it didn't feel like work. That's also why I don't want to gain reputation for the *many* question closings I did.

Comment: Despite the popularity of this view, reputation was *never* any sort of measure of one's technical knowledge or problem-solving abilities. Aside from the fact that upvotes on questions have *always* been rewarded with reputation (albeit at a 1:2 ratio compared to upvotes on answers), even upvotes on answers don't necessarily indicate technical knowledge. Certainly not when you realize that downvotes don't even come close to canceling out upvotes. All reputation is and has ever been is a measure of your *participation* on this site, and thus familiarity with its rules, norms, and customs.

Comment: @DenysSéguret: Yeah, wage doesn't fit perfectly. It's more like awarded prize money for competitions by popular vote. You don't recalculate that, either.

Comment: Claiming that reputation would purely be a measure of participation - like @Cody just did - doesn't make sense to me. If that was the case, we users wouldn't choose whom to award points, it would be awarded, well, for participation. That's not the case.

Comment: @CodyGray - I think most regular users would disagree with that first sentence. One could be highly active and contribute a lot to the site, but if it's all crap and nonsense, reputation would reflect that. Reputation is a measure for **useful** participation, and to be useful on a technical Q&A site, one surely needs some technical skill to be able to ask and answer questions, and as can be seen directly from the list of users with the highest rep, the more skill, the more reputation. You'd think technical knowledge, and lack thereof, would directly correlate to reputation on a site like this

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I think it's the difference between "new upvotes are worth more than old upvotes (we're paying higher now)" and "upvotes should have been worth more (we've miscalculated)". It would be weird if upvotes would count different based on age. IIRC, reputation was re-calculated on all changes to the reputation system in the past.

Comment: @fbueckert I've always thought of reputation points as a proxy for how helpful I've been to others. But answers are much more helpful than questions, so it made sense that answers would be awarded more points than questions.

Comment: Reputation is not, and never should have been considered a "measure of our problem solving ability". In my opinion, the culture of "higher rep users are smarter than lower rep users" is one of, if not *the*, major problem with stack overflow.

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic Not "smarter". Judging by the tooltip of the vote button, they just provide *more helpful answers*. (As in both "more answers" and "better answers").

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic - I'm willing to help out as a surgeon, doesn't mean I should though, seeing as I know nothing about surgery. Providing correct answers is what gives this site value. Providing a whole lot of wrong answers, even though it is contributing, doesn't really add anyhing, other than confusion. I don't think high-rep users feel that they know more **because** they have a higher rep, maybe some, but certainly not most, but high-rep users are probably more likely to comment and correct wrong answers.

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic It is both. Your willingness to help others / the site, and your ability to contribute useful content (as judged by the other users).

Comment: @CodyGray This has been on the [reputation help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) for as long as I can remember: `Reputation is a rough measurement of how much the community trusts you; it is earned by convincing your peers that you know what you’re talking about.` One would think that problem solving and technical abilities would be a prerequisite for convincing peers that I know what I'm talking about. I'm of mixed opinion on this change, but to pretend like reputation has always been about _participation alone_ is rewriting history to defend unpopular changes.

Comment: @DenysSéguret, I have not been doing this as long as you, but I feel the same as you. I like the way you answered this, its what I always told those developers who will rename nameless that I disagreed whenever they said that Stack Overflow just showed employers you have a lot of time on your hands. I would love to know what kind of mindset says SO just shows employers you have too much time on your hands. What exactly does that even mean?

Comment: Well congratulations on reaching 300K anyway. You were at 298K last night. Do you get a unicorn painting now?

Comment: @CodeCaster I mainly get to have to hide my rep from recruiters and employers now that it's a measure of time spent, I guess.

Comment: This entire rant only makes sense if you take as a given that _votes on questions are so easy to acquire as to be meaningless_, and if that's the case, the system was already broken anyway, _because it already rewarded those questions_. If upvotes on questions have become "a measure of the traffic we build" *that's already a big problem*, regardless of how they interact with reputation, because they're fundamental to the design of the site.

Comment: @IMSoP Do you refer to my answer ? Then you read something that wasn't here at all. I never pretended that *"votes on questions are so easy to acquire as to be meaningless"*. Votes on question aren't easy to acquire at all. But they provide little relevance to the question of technical reputation, and shouldn't have to. And yes I've already asserted that questions should not have any impact on reputation (also in order to make it less painful to have her/his question closed or badly received, especially for newcomers, and to make them focus on the problem of getting an answer, not reputation)

Comment: I get way more upvotes on easy answers to stupid questions than on detailed answers to hard questions. The more work I need to put into an answer, the more knowledge it displays, the less reputation I will gain from it. Thus, rep does not display knowledge. It displays how quickly you answer a new, easy question.

Comment: @DenysSéguret Your answer seems to be saying that changing the reputation in this way is the end of Stack Overflow as we know it, because previously reputation was meaningful, and now it won't be. I don't see how that is the case. Questions **always** formed part of reputation, and reputation **always** represented "how much the community trusted you". It has **never** been a score of "problem-solving ability", but a good problem-solving ability is **one of the ways to gain it**, both before and after this change.

Comment: When I first came here, I felt like this was a PRO forum. So I had to be professional myself to get answers. When I was not good enough, people were reacting accordingly. Now, today, saw a sudden gain of about 400 rep points and I feel like I don't deserve them. I got answers to my questions ! That is enough of a reward for asking correctly ! Answer's upvotes should be +15 and questions upvotes still +5

Comment: The effect of gamification should be measured by how many users actually gained 10k/50k/100k rep from posting questions (vs posting answers).

Comment: For users with 50k-60k rep, on average, less than 15% rep comes from asking questions [link](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1148781/perc-of-rep-come-from-asking-question-upvote-only). Less than 7% users within range gain rep mainly from asking questions. While this stat is inaccurate, I think rep change does not affect high-rep users.

Comment: You didn't "build" SO, they did, you are an end-user. The great thing is you can actually just leave, you were also never actually owed any sort of voice in the conversation, there was never even the false pretense that you would have a say into changes of the points scheme. Sorry it hurts to hear that.

Comment: @JPSilvashy - of course, all websites are effectively dictatorships, with an owner that ultimately makes all the decisions.  However, when your site relies on other people creating all the content, for free, you better at least try to make it appear like they have a say, and keep them happy, that's what the gamification and Meta is about. The people who built SO, Jeff and Joel, got that, but they aren't here anymore, and the new leadership seems to be more busy with making money and increasing pageviews, than keeping up the appereance of including the existing users, to make them happy.

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic: *..is not, and never should've been..." I'm afraid that while the second part may be true the first is not. I and many others use rep as a rough measure of everything good, be it intelligence, expertise, or problem-solving skill. I know it's unreliable yet my instinct is treat to high-rep users with deference on all matters.

Comment: I'm sure I'm not the only one that actually is on SO so I can show something to a prospective employer (not doing very well on that yet, eh).  I'm more interested in showing my actual answers (shows technical knowledge + writing skills) than points, but hey, points are a nice summary.  I'd be less opposed to this change if it worked like the question/answer votes split view.  That is, if the total points could be shown as question points + answer points.

Comment: the hypocrisy of pitying about "poor questions" getting rewarded is astonishing..only if you could distinguish the reputation quality of some of the highest earners..most of them earned their 6 or 7 digit reputation by answering poor quality questions, especially during 2008-2014 period

Comment: This is exactly the point, that move could sign the death sentence of SO if answerers go away.

Comment: "But recalculating reputation retroactively is a huge break of trust. A falsification of history. Deceit." I don't think the way they recalculated reputation is a big deal because this is the way they've always done it. When a post gets deleted, the reputation gained/lost from it is erased from history, looking at the user's graph it's like the post was never there.

Comment: Is that really what the community wanted, or is said community already gone? Today I can only see that incompetence is rewarded, while hard questions are being downvoted.

Answer (score 491):

> To that end, if you have questions, concerns, comments, or other
>   feedback about this change, please post it as an answer here.

**Feedback???**

To what end? Decision has already been made, regardless of the negative feedback on the Meta site. One of the questions posted before official announcements and that is not deleted is [Should the weight of question upvotes be increased network-wide?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337843/should-the-weight-of-question-upvotes-be-increased-network-wide)

This decision will be detrimental to the quality of Stack Overflow. I believe it is final nail in the coffin.

## RIP Stack Overflow, welcome Homework Overflow.

---

I will repeat what I said in answer to the linked question because some things you can never say enough times:

> Should the weight of question upvotes be increased network-wide?

## No.

- Answers are more valuable than questions because they require knowledge, giving more reputation to answers rewards learning and acquiring that knowledge.
- Users asking a question (trying to solve problem) will get answers besides the reputation, a solution to their problem which is a reward on its own.
- Reputation unlocks moderation powers - reputation gained through knowledge means moderation will be done by more knowledgeable people and that reduces potential errors.
- We don't need to add more incentive for people to ask questions, especially not on Stack Overflow, there are already way too many poorly researched and poorly asked questions.
- Questions often get upvotes because of "me, too" problems. Someone has a problem, finds the answer on existing question and upvotes both even though question might be less than stellar or even rather poor.

As the end result, giving same reputation for questions as for answers will only reduce overall quality.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about the Meta post. Is this the "less-than-ethical member" the OP here was talking about? Is it someone else and this is just coincidence?

Comment: @Unihedron No. This is not question asked by "less-than-ethical member". There were other questions before this one but they have been deleted. I think some are mentioned in the comments, but you need 10K on Meta in order to see them.

Comment: @Unihedron we don't know who that person is, only that they were not not a moderator at the time (otherwise whey would not have had access to said info)

Comment: Well, yeah, feedback. I'm not running the show here, but I still fundamentally believe that the community has a voice, and as long as it's possible, I'm going to see to it that they have a reasonable way and place to express their opinions. Unilateral decisions by staff have been a fixture of this place [since the Atwood days](https://blog.codinghorror.com/listen-to-your-community-but-dont-let-them-tell-you-what-to-do/), including the original change to halve rep gains from question upvotes (announced and [status-completed] on the same day).

Comment: @CodyGray Back in the Atwood days, those unilateral decisions were actually made for the good of the site's quality, and hence we were happy for our benevolent overlords to make said decisions. Now we have decisions being imposed for "niceness", and today's overlords wonder why they are not trusted.

Comment: "Reputation unlocks moderation powers - reputation gained through knowledge means moderation will be done by more knowledgeable people and that reduces potential errors." This by itself is enough to convince me this is a bad move.

Comment: @CodyGray If we would be able to moderate all poor content fast, then giving more reputation to questions could pass. I still think it is bad idea in any case, but OK... In current situation adding features like this while moderation is in deep sh*** is just adding insult to injury.

Comment: While I agree with a lot of the sentiment in this post, I've always taken issue with the last bullet point style of thinking. Up voting on 'me too' questions.
While it is somewhat possible to objectively decided if a question is good or not, really that comes from consensus. If someone asks a question and gets and answer, and others find that answer by searching for similarly phrased questions, surely that makes a question good.
I get that we want 'good' questions by SO standards and to encourage that to new users, but if a question helps you find a good answer, then the question is good.

Comment: @CodyGray - "I still fundamentally believe that the community has a voice" What does "has a voice" mean? How is it different from not having a voice?

Comment: @MikeS159 Question is do the "How to format string in Java" type of questions deserve as much reputation as they have gained. Yes, you can more easily find answer to such questions here than in official documentation and answers on SO are often more detailed and better than documentation. But you reward answers to such questions, not the no-effort two line question.

Comment: `Reputation unlocks moderation powers - reputation gained through knowledge means moderation will be done by more knowledgeable people and that reduces potential errors.`  There's already enough bad reviewers in each of the queues, and the people who just blindly upvote every single question (I'm talking people with 10K+ upvotes and no downvotes) are just going to accelerate that influx now that questions are worth twice as much.  Asking crappy questions and getting upvotes is easy.  I for one welcome our new participation-trophy overlords.

Comment: @Scott Umm, pretty sure the answer to that question is self-evident. The difference would look something like shutting down the Meta sites. Please don't take this as any sort of hint that is going to happen. I created this question with the express purpose of allowing community members to constructively make their points of view known, pretty much *exactly* as it has happened. I don't know that the feedback will have any effect, but I *do* know that staff members are reading it, and regardless, I think being able to make one's opposition view known has value.

Comment: @CodyGray Please don't take "feedback" comments personally (I hope you didn't) we all know or at least hope so that there are some staff members that **do listen** to the community. It is not easy to express disappointments when on the other side is someone that is not even closely responsible. I am sorry that we are shooting the messengers in this process.

Comment: I only wish i could upvote this twice. I think every single point you make here is the absolute truth, including the fact that they don't care at all about the community feedback on any change. I too think this may indeed by the final nail in the coffin.

Comment: @CodyGray - one evident meaning of "having a voice" is that you can speak. Presumably you didn't mean that, because you wouldn't need to state that you 'fundamentally believe' something so obvious. Another meaning is that what we say counts for something. But I don't think you meant that. So what does 'having a voice' mean? It's okay to admit if no one cares what we think. That's generally considered not having a voice. They probably should shut the meta site down. It would be more honest.

Comment: It counts for something to me, @Scott, and I know it counts for something to at least *some* of the staff members. Does it count for something with the actual decision-makers? I don’t know. Maybe? But I get that it feels more like “maybe not”, and I get (oh, so I ever empathize!) that is very frustrating. But that’s no reason to stop speaking out, both when you’re happy and when you’re not. Importantly, it should count for something to *you* (where “you” is all community members).

Comment: At the end the decision makers must understand, earlier or later, that an answer is more worth than a question. And they must realize that an expert who answers someone else's question has, up to some point, the natural right to put some requirements on the standards of the question and the way it is asked. That has been the case since the early days of mankind and actually most people who ask a question will understand that. Sometimes it's just that they don't know the standard, which SO has to better communicate (since the early days)

Comment: ps: I admit that SO has gone better at communicating the standards. But it needs more and more iterations, including technology etc, etc. If I had a team of developers, I could name a couple of points that could be done to improve the experience for people who asks questions, other than bumping the rep for their question. Most people who like to ask a question don't even care about rep actually (or their personal pronoun :) ), they care about the answer. I can say that from the people I've learned at work at least. From there I would say make it 0 rep :)

Comment: ... but at the same time make it simpler for people to get what they are looking for. I'm not saying it's that simple, but that should be the main effort. .... (My comments were in response to @CodyGray's last comment)

Comment: I'd still like to see SO a site where Stuart Marks and Brian Goetz have more reputation than entry-level dev with top-voted primitive question like this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/how-do-i-read-convert-an-inputstream-into-a-string-in-java

Comment: 'Welcome Homework Overflow' I think is the best way to summarize this change. We already have this problem now - now it's just going to be worse. I will say, a lot of homework questions are from new accounts, whereby downvoting will never negatively impact them because that user will never use their account again past the one question to solve their homework. But in general, I agree with the OP - homework questions, or extremely poorly researched questions that a quick Google search could solve, should be removed, not encouraged.

Comment: I've only asked 5 questions in the whole lifetime of using SO. Only one of my questions has ever been answered (by another person). The oldest, has been asked 4 1/2 years ago, and only 171 views, with 0 answers and even 0 comments on the question. I attribute that entirety of that to the gargantuan amount of noise this site generates with "how do I hello world?" type questions, which completely mask any questions that might have any merit, or problem that can't be solved via a Google search. We need to cut down on the poor questions and noise, whereby this change seems to be increasing it.

Answer (score 301):

People asking questions are already getting the additional reward of having their questions answered. Increasing reputation gain from upvotes will (in combination with the bad practice of some people to upvote downvoted questions to "balance out" the vote) only encourage people to post more questions, period.

I do not expect this change to have any net positive effect at all. Just an increased influx of bad questions.

Comment: I don't expect the change to make any difference whatsoever in the number or quality of questions asked.

Comment: That would be the best-case scenario.

Comment: @MarkRansom correct, not in the number or quality, but in the way they are valued

Comment: Bad questions shouldn't be upvoted, so why would it make a difference?

Comment: @user253751 Because bad questions are being upvoted all the time. Welcome to reality.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Then we need to address that problem. The alternative is to remove voting from questions altogether, not to leave it there but divorce it from the reputation system.

Comment: "only encourage people to post more questions, period."

It would appear this is the goal of the new CEO. Improve [this](https://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/stackoverflow.com)

Comment: @user253751 They _shouldn't_ be, but they are.  Very, very often.  For all sorts of reasons.

Answer (score 236):

Why ***this***?

Why ***now***?

Why is there more value being placed on questions - which are the more inexhaustible resource in the Q&A ecosystem?

What does this accomplish beyond warm and fuzzies for the question askers who ask a reasonable question?

Comment: Must... Implement... Bounties... For... Meta...

Comment: Why not now? And if it achieves the latter, is that not enough? Not that I have any real answers for you, but you're making it sound kinda good to me.

Comment: @Bart:  I would have valued a responsive profile page higher than reevaluating whether or not we should give questions 10 rep as opposed to 5.  The reason is simple:  questions are what *get* people to the site.  Answers are what *keep* people on the site.  I would've thought that this was a settled matter by now.

Comment: You know, I was on board with that for the longest time. But given the waves of utter drivel I don't even care to answer, I'm kinda okay with rewarding those who still manage to stand out. I don't really mind this change. And as for "features" that have priority, in any decently large organisation there are multiple things in development at all times. Something being released earlier doesn't necessarily imply higher priority.

Comment: @Bart:  I just completed two and a half days of Agile training which is why my mind is still pretty amped up on the whole priority thing.  What I remember is, if a feature which wasn't a priority was released before other prioritized features, then that means the team isn't building the right thing.  I won't speak to Stack Exchange's priorities since I'm not privy to them. But, one half of me questions who their customers are, and the other half already knows.

Comment: @Makoto Agile training. God that brings back memories. But I've also been on the end where gamers complained loudly about "ridiculous updates" we made while not fixing core issues, when in fact we were working hard at both, but the released updates were just easy low hanging fruit we could get out quickly. Aaaanywayyy, I'm going off topic ;)

Comment: (yeah the same negative impression was given of "low hanging fruit" too)

Comment: If you haven’t already, please read the updates to [this answer](/a/391248), specifically the bottom non-quoted portion. I linked to it from the question, but it’s important because I think it answers what you’re asking. It explains why this—it was a mistake all along; there are better, more effective solutions to the actual problem; and it’s finally being corrected. It’s really not a warm fuzzies issue. I thought the same thing when I first heard it, until I read my own explanation. (Wait, what?!) Why *not* now? It takes a lot less development work than building a new profile page.

Comment: @CodyGray:  I skimmed that answer and - in fairness - it *was* trying to justify this.  I don't *agree* with the justification, because it's basically stating that there were no pearls in answers, and that both questions and answers are equally valuable.  This is ***categorically*** false.  While a good question can spark a great answer, the world only really cares about the great answers, empirically demonstrated by me not answering any questions for the last, say, six months, and only looking for answers to questions (and sometimes failing at that).

Comment: @CodyGray:  I also only referenced the profile page as tongue-in-cheek.  We've had a responsive site for what, a year or so now?  The profile page seems to be lagging behind, and I don't quite understand why that is.  No one's sharing why that is.  So, when I see things that don't quite tie up loose ends, it's in my natural wont to question the decision.

Comment: One last parting note on this @CodyGray - just because it's *easy* to build doesn't mean it's the most valuable thing to build.  I maintain I would have valued a fixing-up of the UX as opposed to this change, which comes across as unnecessary and a bit more like a violation of expectations - something that [Denys concisely stated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/391259/1079354) far better than I could, since I know I'm totally incoherent righ tnow.

Comment: Isn't the implementation trivial in this case? Changing a single configuration value in one place and perhaps forcing/scheduling a recalculation?

Comment: I'm growing tired of shouting to the wind.  **Triviality does not factor in here.**  I'm talking about ***value***.  Value to the customers.  If it's the case that Stack Exchange has decided that their definition of "customer" now means "users who just ask questions", then I am wasting my time.  If it *doesn't*, then we get to look at others - like myself - who use the site on a mobile device.

Comment: A cynical person might say that the intention is to punish the people who have answered many more questions than they have asked and then participated in MSE/MSO to downvote some recent changes. The punishment is that their relative reputation is reduced, e.g., overnight I have gone from page 220 down to page 251 in the user reputation leagues. I have been devalued by more than 10%. But it could plausibly be construed as an unintentional side-effect.

Comment: _"What does this accomplish beyond warm and fuzzies for the question askers who ask a reasonable question?"_ Nail meet head

Comment: Do you guys really think that it is us regular (and not so much) users who are the customers for the site? We are equally as much customers for SO as we are for, say, FB. Job advertisers are the real customers here and they demand more conversion in exchange for _money_. And when money start to play their part everyone else shuts up. All that recent welcomeness bs is only an excuse for the owners' greed for more $.

Comment: @ayorgo:  It's not like the question askers are bringing money in, either.

Comment: @Makoto they increase chances of ads being clicked on I guess. And since the no-of-answerers to no-of-askers ratio is pretty small, someone high up the management ladder with a narrow understanding of how the site works may be pushing this to increase the total audience at the expense of quality to make the quarterly report look better or smth. At least this is the only way I can make sense of what's going on.

Comment: "What does this accomplish beyond warm and fuzzies for the question askers who ask a reasonable question?" Warm and fuzzies for people who ask unreasonable questions. Also warm and fuzzies and a sense of self righteousness for the people demanding it.

Answer (score 177):

The main problem, for me, is that asking questions doesn't require you to become truly familiar with the site and its quality standards. And handing out privileges that require familiarity and knowledge of the site is problematic.

Answering a substantial amount of questions requires users to show an interest in the site and shows a willingness to help others. Those are the users I'd like to have reviewing questions, and would trust with the privileges that come with reputation. Asking a substantial amount of questions, however, requires only visiting the site when you have a question (instead of actively visiting to look for new questions), and can be motivated purely by a selfish need. For these users I have strong doubts.

Take [the first edit of this recent HNQ](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/58832269/1) for example. That would've netted this user 160 rep already, and assuming this bug hangs around, might very well get in the neighborhood of 2K over a couple of months. This same user has edited in *Help!!!!!!!!!!* after *Please Help* was removed. I'd rather not have such users gain access to review queues or the privilege to edit without going through the queue, even though their contribution might be valuable.

Comment: You’d rather that user gain only 80 rep, and only ~1k over a couple of months? Aside from that, I’m not convinced that posting answers really shows that one groks the purpose of the site, either.

Comment: @CodyGray - I'm not convinced the people running the site groks the purpose of the site either. Most of us do this solely for fun and personal learning, and the fake internet points are fun and competitive, nothing more, they don't pay the rent, yet we care enough and have worked hard enough, that just giving them away retroactively seems wrong. This all worked 8 years ago, users joined and become active members back then as well, and if it isn't working now, something has clearly changed, and it probably isn't the community?

Comment: @adeneo StackOverflow isn't " just giving them away". They are awarding participation points equally to the two groups of people participating with the site.

Comment: "Aside from that, I’m not convinced that posting answers really shows that one groks the purpose of the site, either."

wait, WHAT?

Comment: The problem is probably not the reputation count itself (though I'd prefer a seperate count for Q+A reputation), but the fact that privileges are based on reputation. That's why it seems unfair. IMO privileges shouldn't be awarded based on reputation but rather earned based on participation and other factors. Perhaps earning badges should unlock privileges, giving more value to badges and at the same time providing the evidence of participation.

Comment: If votes on questions are meaningful at all, then asking questions _that receive positive votes_ does require the same familiarity with the site as writing answers _that receive positive votes_. If votes on questions are _not_ meaningful, then that is a problem with the voting system, not the reputation system.

Comment: I think there should be a system in place where a newbie has to answer 5 questions and get at least one (1) upvote on them all before gaining the privilege to ask questions. This way there would be more incentive for newcomers to compose high quality questions already from the beginning, contributing to the community from day one.  One could even give the first 5 upvoted answers a x2 reputation bonus just to make it even more attractive and rewarding for people who just joined. But after that go back to how it always has been.

Comment: @silkfire ...and if it was in place, I would probably never use SE at all. I started on ruSO with Lua questions, which is not nearly as popular as JS, not to mention that ruSO is far less active than main site. If there is **one** good Lua question per day on ruSO, it is a very good day.

Comment: Imho reputation shouldn't earn privileges at all. It should be just for bragging rights only. It's the fallacy of the "Peter principle".

Answer (score 158):

Yay for better rewards on good questions, but where are the rewards (or acknowledgement) for finding duplicates?

I can imagine this change will create a brief rise in voting rings and duplicate questions asked by users only interested in reputation with no regard to overall quality so to me, it will be more beneficial for the "Stack Overflow veterans" by rewarding them with their experience in locating existing questions. There aren't many >20k users asking questions regularly since they're able to use the 12 years of existing content effectively.

Comment: I like this. Finding accurate dupes is so terribly under-rated. But, it's "Stack Overflow" not "StackOverflow" ;-)

Comment: What, isn't fighting other gold badge holders who reopen the question you just dupe-voted, because they had just typed an answer when you did so, reward enough? (And no, that's a bit tongue-in-cheek, this doesn't happen more often than me wrongfully dupe-voting).

Comment: @CodeCaster - Its not a real fight unless they're over 100k rep and telling you you're making it an unwelcoming place too

Comment: [The r-word has been banned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281787) (and removed from *[The Many Memes of Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478)*). *[Help vampire](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/)* is also on its way out.

Comment: @PeterMortensen - Interesting, I didn't know that thanks. I'll have to start using something else to call these users instead but nothing else I can think of at the minute has the same ring to it. Note: I'd never call a user this directly, I refer only to the act of "rep whoring" and its participants as a collective

Comment: I'd upvote this 100 if I could.  I spend most of my time in the PHP tag, and most of my time is spent finding dupe targets.  The questions that are actually worthy of new answers are few and far between.

Comment: I don't care that much about getting more reputation from closing questions. Instead we should *devalue reputation gained from closed questions*, as has been proposed so often.

Comment: I don't think that now reputation means what it used to. This change is similar to printing money, you have more, but they become worthless...

Comment: @meJustAndrew That would only be true if the amount you need to have to get the privileges also increased proportionally

Comment: I don't say it lost its value from a functional point of view, as usage on the site (even though I believe that should be done as well, if we will keep on having this change) but from a psychological point of view. When I was looking to a higher rep user, I was having some sort of intuition of his contribution. Now that changed a bit.

Comment: *"but where are the rewards (or acknowledgement) for finding duplicates"* I don't know if we *should* get rewards for these, however, I also think that people *shouldn't* get rewarded for answering questions that *are* duplicates. I constantly see a couple of users that consistently answer obvious duplicates when they should be closing them (as they're a "gold badger").

Answer (score 149):

As a longtime Stack Overflow contributor who has answered over 2,000+ questions and asked none, it feels like this is inadvertently affecting those of us who have primarily answered questions as opposed to asking them.

What exactly is the benefit in doing this retroactively? Why rewrite reputation?

Aside from that, this change is still disproportionate and skews reputation because question downvotes still only result in a net loss of -2 reputation.

At least double question downvotes to -4 reputation to balance out downvotes against upvotes.

Comment: I’m not clear on how this disadvantages you as an answerer, rather than an asker. By definition, it has no effect on your reputation earned. This is not a zero-sum game. It seems perfectly valid to have two different routes to earning privileges: asking or answering. The benefit of doing this retroactively is fairness. Also see my retrospective linked from the question: essentially, Jeff’s original decision to reduce rep upvote weight has been deemed to have been a misstep, so it’s being reversed with the benefit of hindsight. The upvote/downvote disproportionality is there for answers, too.

Comment: @CodyGray - That is exactly it, my reputation remains unchanged along with anyone else who has never asked a question, yet we are retroactively increasing everyone else's reputation which consequently devalues the reputation of those who only answered questions. It's basically conditional reputation inflation.

Comment: I agree, I've answered 7500'ish questions, and never asked one either, so this change doesn't affect me at all really. Still, a lot of other users will quite suddenly receive a humongous amount of reputation from the retroactive change, users ranging from many of the sites top users, that have created canonical questions that they have answered themselves, to be able to close questions on common topics, that have thousands of upvotes over the years, to users that haven't visited the site in years, but asked a really basic question 13 or so years ago.

Comment: The relative ranking changes will be interesting when they get recalculated in a couple hours. Except for the very top scorers, I expect question answerers will drop, and askers will zoom up.

Comment: Hmmm. My rank dropped 2100 places, but my percentile value stayed about the same because of a large number of additional users that crossed the 100 point threshold thanks to their rep boost.

Comment: @CodyGray Why asking questions should mean earning privileges? Let's say I decide to spend an hour answering questions. It will be hard work, I will have to be quick, have the knowledge, often do some research, etc. I can now spend that same hour asking questions, I can ask many more questions than I can answer. In extreme scenarios, I could just figuratively throw shit on the wall hoping that some of it will stick, and if it will, I will eventually get moderating privileges. This makes very little sense. Again, it seems like VIEWS > MERIT, as this earns SO money.

Comment: @CodyGray it **does** change **a lot** for the answerers vs the askers. It changes their **ranking**. This ***retroactive*** goalpost shifting has cost me 255 places in my ranking. The rep number in points is **meaningless** in itself, it's the ranking that counts. Just like with money, there's inflation with time, so points have no meaning except through the derived ranking. And you have just changed that meaning. **ReTrOaCtiVeLy .** Make whatever friggin change you like, but doing it **ReTrOaCtiVeLy** is beyond outrageous.

Comment: @WillNess What are you referring to when you say ranking?

Comment: @TylerH [this](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow/2018-01-01/849891#849891). I was 2080th, yesterday. Now I'm 2335th.

Comment: The fact that this incentivizes asking questions is what worries me.  Yes, we want people to ask questions, but I'm still of the opinion that [asking a question should be the last thing you do on your research road](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/691711).  I wonder if this was a reason that answer was deleted at one point.

Comment: @WillNess No one looks at that for any reason other than to look at it though. It has no bearing on anything other than itself. Aside from that, your ranking can change anyway by that many positions (or more) just from normal site activity.

Comment: @zero298 I'm sure it was part of it. The company (including the CMs) care about profit because it's what benefits them as a company and as individuals. The bottom line is quality harms profit, so they're doing what they can to eliminate it.

Comment: @TylerH of course it can change, and does / did, according to the rules. And now they changed those rules, ***retroactively***. that's the only thing I'm objecting to,  really; otherwise I don't care what they do with their site. By they changed what *I did* here, in effect.

Comment: @TylerH also it *does* have a bearing on one more thing: that "top 0.5% overall" next to a user's name. So yes, people do see that, a lot.

Comment: @WillNess People may see it but no one cares.

Comment: @TylerH feeling a bit omniscient are we. and dismissive, too.

Comment: @WillNess OK, let me rephrase: no one cares *for any reason that matters*. If someone is changing how they interact with you in real life (or even here on the site), either by offering you some respect, a job offer, a book deal, a conference gig, etc. vs *not* doing those things, based purely on whether you're top 0.22% vs top 0.20% on Stack Overflow, then you're better off not dealing with them at all in the first place. They're clearly placing way too much value in something that doesn't accurately represent said value and never claimed to in the first place.

Comment: Feels to me like SO is saying "We don't really care about you helping people and sharing your knowledge - We value more people asking for help", which doesn't resonate well with me.

Comment: @TylerH yeah, [literally no one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391250/upvotes-on-questions-will-now-be-worth-the-same-as-upvotes-on-answers#comment740215_391250) cares. let's eliminate the rep entirely then, no one cares / should care about it in RL either.

Comment: @WillNess Again, someone complaining about the thing in and of itself, and you using that as evidence that people care for a good reason, is a little tautological. Aside from that, your comment is inaccurate: you indicate we should eliminate rep, but what we're talking about are the social rankings, not rep. They could certainly do away with the reputation leagues pages and associated features and still keep the reputation system; you'd simply never know whether you were in the top 0.2% or bottom 0.2%, which would probably be better, anyway.

Comment: @TylerH I've tired of this discussion, but for some reason what's crystal clear to me is muddy to you: your argument goes both ways, the rep and the ranking the same. just my opinion; your mileage clearly varies. -- 'coulda woulda' doesn't count: we have *both* rep and rank now. BTW, interesting to see what reaction it'd get if you'd proposed to get rid of the ranking leagues (except, there's SEDE...). If you do, could you please do me a favor and ping me here, as I'm extremely likely to miss it since I almost never follow the meta. Happy trails,

Comment: @Varin Your hypothetical scenario is not accurate.  On SO, you can [ask a maximum of 6 questions per day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/494499) if this answer is up to date.  On top of that, your questions have to be actually good to get upvotes.  People don't just throw upvotes at bad or duplicate questions.  Additionally, you would hit the rep cap of 200 per day just the same as you would for answering. The point is, there are already other measures in place to limit the benefit gained by question askers.

Comment: @Steve-o169 You can identify a fairly new tech, identify questions that have lots of upvotes in an older, similar tech and ask literally the same questions under different tags. If it's only 6 questions per day, that will take me 5-10 minutes with some prior investigation. The main point is: ```questions != answers``` in terms of how valuable they are, therefore they should not carry same weight. I gained 20% extra rep through this change and I rather give it back as I don't feel like I earned it.

Comment: @Varin So say you do that (which is in itself, exploiting the rep system for your own gain) -- what's to stop another user from answering each of those 6 questions to get the same amount (or more) of rep?  If the questions are good ones that need to be answered, why is this a problem?  If the limit is 6 per day, 50 per 30 days, is that not already limiting the amount of rep to be gained by asking?  This format already has safeguards in place against the flood of bad questions.  Probably not enough, but reputation earned for good questions is not a bad thing, IMO.

Comment: @Varin -- In theory, a good question should require as much research and effort as a good answer.  It's up to the community to recognize and upvote those questions and downvote any that do not meet the standard.

Answer (score 99):

I'm really not sure that this is going to really help things, if I'm honest. Something that many of us see (especially at the weekends), are a lot of low quality questions. A lot of new users don't really *bother* to take the time to read the tour, or the help pages, and especially understand what an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is, making their questions difficult to answer.

From someone who solely contributions against [tsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tsql), [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) and its version tags (e.g. [sql-server-2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2016)) one of the biggest problems I see on an hourly basis (possibly more) is a question showing no SQL, and images for data, and no effort. These questions are truly awful from a SQL point of view. The data isn't consumable so if I (or any one else) wants to contribute and **test** our answers we have to *transcribe* that information, which can be very time consuming. But these questions ***do*** get upvotes from people, as it "looks" like the OP has supplied the information we "need" (it's just useless to anyone who *wants* to help). This means that it now takes 5 down votes to negate that, not the 2.5 it used to.

I'm actually for new users getting the needed reputation to be able to contribute (being able to comment on other questions is a big part of being able to contribute on any SE site), but I think there needs to be a better way than this. Perhaps, rather than doubling the reputation you get for an upvote on a question, you should get more on accepting an answer. Acceptance rate can be pretty low, and for a new user I think getting them to understand the importance of it, with a bigger reputation "carrot" could be a good way.

Hey, perhaps a question that gets a lot of high voted (define high) answers should reward the asker too. If an answer to the question gets 10 votes, the asker gets 10 rep; and repeat for each answer (and each 10 of votes, i.e. @ 20, 30, etc). There are some questions on the SE site that have 10's of answers and many of those can have 50+ votes. That would be a really good way to rewarding the asker, in my opinion. They have asked a good question and got upvoted for that, and also they attracted some great answers, which has contributed to the community; and the asker is (effectively) rewarded for *good* answers as they were the reason they were contributed to the site.

*Edit: Something I've noticed very quickly from myself is that since this announcement I am now far quicker at downvoting questions. This is something that previously I wasn't; I would comment first, wait for a response, and downvote accordingly (if no response received or request for improvements were ignored). That isn't true any more, I'm downvoting with comments (or upvoting an existing comment). This is especially true for the question types outlined above (lack of MRE, images for date, etc, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58900728/sql-server-agent-deletes-records-at-midnight), with no code to even debug but has an upvote).*

*Why am I now quicker to downvote? Because these truly poor questions should* not *be getting 10 reputation from a a single vote, when there is not a single sign of effort, or useable piece of code/data. I very much doubt that my changed behaviour is an intention of the outlined changes in the OP.*

Comment: Nice ideas here, all better than the current change.

Comment: Up you go! The one with acceptance of the answers should do it, especially because many newcomers do not bother to accept an answer

Comment: It sounds like the problem here is "these questions do get upvotes from people". That needs fixing regardless of what is done to reputation, because scores are also used for other purposes.

Comment: Fully agree. moreover, I will now actively go through my old upvotes on questions an will unupvote any that I find I did as an encouragement, on the more poorly asked questions. Yes I did that a lot. Now I won't. An I will downvote without hesitation now, too.

Comment: You probably won't be able to unupvote, @WillNess ; not unsure the question has been edited. Unless they don't have the same rules as answer upvotes.

Comment: @Larnu oh I'm editing them, be sure of that. Any that I find lacking, and not deserving of my upvote under the new value system, I'm editing and un-upvoting. The good ones I don't touch of course.

Comment: Editting to unvote seems like an unexpected loophole. :/

Comment: heh. they could've discussed it with. the. community. first, could they? :)

Comment: I had the same thoughts about being more likely to downvote if question downvote rep isn't also increased.  I can easily justify a "lack of research effort" downvote on a lot of questions.

Comment: Some really good points as alternatives with reasoning +1. Especially the answer upvotes to asked question reps which for sure improves and encourages the site quality content wise.

Answer (score 91):

I will be honest, I mostly down vote. I exhaust my votes almost every day and 98% of it are down votes. It is much more difficult to find either a good answer or a good question to up vote. On one hand this change makes me happy, because people who asked **really** good questions will be rewarded, but this has also a very serious adverse effect. 2 reasons:

1. Sometimes I make exceptions to my voting habits and I upvote the question purely because the answers are extraordinary and I want this question to pop up in the search more often. This is bad... I feel bad doing this, because I reward a bad question for wrong reasons. But I know that if someone searches for a duplicate target they do not see the answer score, they see the question score!
2. **We edit the questions!** People post awful questions. Sometimes they are completely unreadable. We as a community edit them to make them at least answerable and if they attract good answers, we tend to polish those questions even more. The end result is that the extremely poor effort of the asker might be rewarded due to our hard work in editing.
   We are even encouraged to edit the questions when we answer. I think there are few badges around this topic. **Why is the OP, who couldn't care less about the quality when they asked it, be rewarded for our hard work?**

Comment: *"I will be honest, I mostly down vote. I exhaust my votes almost every day and 98% of it are down votes.*" I'm not sure that's something to be "proud" of (I'm not saying you are). Using all your votes in a day mainly on downvotes is a significant number. I admit, I'm sparing in my upvotes as the difference in rep is a lot, but I prefer to comment and explain first. If I get no response, or my (polite) request for improvements is batted away, then I downvote. but I don't think I'd ever hope to go through a day and use "98%" of my daily votes on downvotes.

Comment: @Larnu I invite you to [tag:web] and [tag:php] tags. Try to find a decent question to answer.

Comment: I don't doubt it's as bad as the sql tags, don't worry @Dharman . :) (I see a few of the bad `php` ones from the SQL side anyway. Loved one today which said that the results were different in PHP to SSMS, but provided no code, and no data /facepalm .

Comment: When I was actively voting, I tended to be very reserved about downvoting questions. If I were still active, this would be the go-ahead to hand out question downvotes without even thinking twice on all but actually good questions.

Comment: @hatchet-ReinstateMonica Fully agree. Even more, I will now actively go through my old upvotes on questions an will unupvote any that I find I did as an encouragement, on the more poorly asked questions. Yes I did that a lot. Now I won't.

Comment: @WillNess Then it sounds like you were voting wrong, and breaking this habit is a good thing. For votes to be useful _for anything_, whether it's reputation or just ranking search results, they need to reflect quality, not sympathy.

Comment: @IMSoP got the message: "no more being nice and welcoming". as I said somewhere else on this entry, I only did this for Qs which were good at the core and only superficially - or initially - bad, which if I felt received their downvotes unfairly. I'll be more skimpy with the upvotes now. that's just how it is.

Comment: @WillNess That's not what I said at all. Feel free to be nice and welcoming _but don't use the up vote button to do so_. Maybe leave a note saying "there's the beginning of a good question here, but you need to fix these things before it deservers an upvote".

Comment: The community also edits answers. Are there any reputation-sharing mechanisms for answers that don't also apply to questions?

Comment: Downvoting is important. don't feel guilty using it. It's the only way to sieve the sand. Don't feel guilty about upvoting questions due to them bringing in good answers either because that meams the question was useful.

Answer (score 89):

#### I believe the approach of this is **entirely wrong.**

There are for sure positive and negative effects of this change which can be debated for long, I am not condemning the change itself, but the way it has been taken:

> Unfortunately, a less-than-ethical member of the larger Stack Exchange moderator community leaked this private communication to the public...

I believe that the right approach here would have been to **let the community decide** if this change should be done, or not, as it changes the community and the interactions between the people here, not the site, the ads, or things more related to the site.

This attitude is the thing that should really be changed!

Comment: Up'd for "This attitude is the thing that should really be changed!".

Comment: I agree that the community should have been consulted, and that they should have had a chance to raise their objections first. Asking the moderators was a good and very welcome first step, but it isn't sufficient going forward. That said, you are incorrect in implying that The Powers That Be making unilateral decisions without consulting the community is something new. It really isn't. Jeff Atwood was the one who said: ["Listen to Your Community, But Don't Let Them Tell You What to Do"](https://blog.codinghorror.com/listen-to-your-community-but-dont-let-them-tell-you-what-to-do/).

Comment: [Jeff's original decision to decrease the weight of upvotes on questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/03/19/important-reputation-rule-changes/) (the change this one is effectively reversing) was not reached in consultation with the community, either. It was a unilateral dictate made by Jeff. Note the date on that blog post: March 19, 2010. That's the same date on [the associated Meta Q&A](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/42769), and, in fact, the same date that said Meta Q&A was tagged [[meta-tag:status-completed]]. Most of the community seemed to agree, but that was a happy coincidence.

Comment: Aside from that, the reason I make the claim about ethics that I do is because the moderators were *specifically* requested not to share the information in public, as a condition of their having been given priority access to the team's plans. Whether or not you think the community should have been involved, disclosing information that you are explicitly asked not to disclose is a major violation of trust, and puts moderators (as representatives of their community) in the same boat as what we've been accusing Stack Exchange employees of doing: violating trust. It's not a good look.

Comment: Does it violate work ethics? Yes, absolutely. I wouldn't do that myself, I don't want to break trust. But when someone finds it such an important matter that they prioritize their own moral values above work ethics, try to think about where they are coming from, because calling out poor ethics doesn't surface the problem, it hides it.

Comment: That might be a compelling argument if magic Internet points were somehow a *moral* issue, @Unihedron. We're not talking a whistleblower announcing that Stack Exchange is funding genocide in third-world countries. Furthermore, there was no brink. The discussions between staff and moderators were still ongoing. We were still having a productive exchange about our concerns and how to modify the proposed policy to maximize benefit to all parties. Anyway...this will be the last thing I say about the "leak", because it has nothing to do with the discussion at hand.

Comment: I'm not interested in rep, I'm merely backing the "This attitude is the thing that should really be changed!" sentiment. Passive-aggressively calling out on a moderator who would otherwise be and have been representing and acting in the interests of your own community is pretty insincere, even if justified. There are other ways to go about it, like accounting for it in far more appropriate ways than rambling about it in a one-sided announcement main post. That's, of course, my own opinion based on what I've seen, I'm not here to teach you what to do (and obviously no such authority).

Comment: @CodyGray I want to thank you for all the effort you are putting into communicating to everyone this change and for providing a bridge between the community and the SE team. You deserve being a moderator, and you are doing an amazing job here!

Comment: not the *retroactive* aspect of it. *that* just can't be condoned in any way.

Comment: Regarding parallels to decisions made by Jeff Atwood - Jeff had a *lot* more credit in the trust bank than the current SO management does.

Comment: I've watched this echo chamber effect escalate over the last 2-3 years now driven by the face of SE apologizing or allowing for the interpretation of an admission for company decisions that won't be reversed. Now SE is in a position where most changes they make are met with hostility and frankly melodramatic reactions. SE being SE, I'm sure they're aware of this schism, but one of two things need to happen. Anticipate common reactions and address them pre-emptively when making & posting the decision, or if the motives aren't aligned with users / can't be mentioned, then don't apologize for it.

Comment: @person27 I believe you are right about the two potential ways of developing the interaction between SE and the community further on, but we will see how things evolve...

Answer (score 87):

I'm quite neutral towards this change; I won't go throwing around terms like "reputation inflation" and "welcome wagon", because I couldn't care less how much reputation other users have. What I am wondering is: who will this benefit, and how?

As far as I know, a question asker couldn't give a rat's ass whether their question is at +5 or -5, as long as they get an answer. They also don't care whether that question gains them -10 or +50 reputation. Newbies ask questions because they want answers, not because they want reputation points.

If someone wants [the most basic privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), they'll have to edit a few posts and post a good answer or three and they can vote and comment.

So again: what's the benefit, and for whom? I can't imagine a help vampire seeing a +5000 reputation recalculation along with a nice message in their profile go *"Oh now I'll spend some more effort at my next question!"*, for example.

Comment: I don't have real strong feelings either. But at the moment it feels like, "We're getting negative attention for awful things we did. Here's some free points!"

Comment: Many users [want](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173) [to comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252133) (in general, not just related to their own questions) and now it only requires half the effort (if only asking questions).

Comment: The data from [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386178/data-science-time-june-2019-and-the-tumbleweed-badge) suggests people do care what their question was voted.  Getting an upvote is on par with getting an answer when bringing someone back.  Getting a downvote discourages some people from returning, even if they get an answer.  And if you're in a niche tag, you can expect to get no votes in either direction.

Comment: @Troyen that's about votes, not reputation. An upvote is an upvote, whether it yields 0 or 10 reputation.

Comment: I was addressing your line "As far as I know, a question asker couldn't give a rat's ass whether their question is at +5 or -5, as long as they get an answer."  I also contend that the amount of points earned from votes _do_ matter.  It takes me longer to research and write questions on some other SE sites than it does answers.

Comment: Maybe we could rephrase the question to "Why do we consider questions to be worth less than answers" Is a question that 10 people think was good or useful worth half as much as an answer that 10 people found useful? There is also the fact that people tend to only upvote the answer that helped them and not the question that prompted the answer.

Comment: There are those of us out there who consider ourselves "askers" not "answerers".  Sure, getting the answer itself is fantastic, and I don't really care about this change either way, but we do exist.  :)

Comment: "What's the benefit, and for whom?" As someone who was just given access to the review queues for the first time as a result of the recalc, I can't help but wonder if this isn't part of an ill-conceived strategy by Stack staff to try and make up for the recent mass exodus of moderators by throwing new privileges at everyone.

Answer (score 82):

My real issue with this change is this graph (lifted from [the Stack Overflow Data Analytics](http://stackoverflow.com/site-analytics) page, a 25k+ user [privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics)):

[image: q&a graph]

Since the initial drop after the site peaked in 2014, questions have actually stayed *reasonably* consistent—but answers have dropped to the point where there's now around the same number of answers and questions. This either means that more questions are only seeing a single answer, or more questions are simply going unanswered. (In reality, it's probably a bit of both.) I don't believe that is the model where SO works most effectively (it instead being that there's *multiple* answers per question generally, and the *best* one is voted up.)

This says to me that, as a community / site / group of users etc.—we're struggling to *effectively* answer most of the questions we have already. I can't see how a focus on encouraging more questions is going to help that trend.

Comment: This graph makes sense because a lot of questions have been asked before. Instead of answering them, they are closed as duplicates, where most of the time OP still gets their solution even not through an answer.

Comment: I can only speak to the tags I mainly work in, more specifically ms-word: There are lots of unanswered questions, mainly because poor questions are not getting enough close/delete votes to remove them from the site. Also, there are so few people *answering* in the tag that it's unusual for there to be more than one reply. Side note: even when an answer is posted it's often not marked as "the" answer, commented on by the OP or even up-voted.

Comment: I found a similar graph (by month) with better axis labels https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/59302/questions-and-answers-per-month#graph

Comment: the query doesn't filter out questions with negative votes or questions that are deleted. Also answers that are downvoted are not filtered out either. I adjusted for that https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1148533/questions-and-answers-per-month#graph as you can see there is a slightly wider gap now. The original point still stands, of course. Not enough answers compared to questions

Comment: What is the dips? Christmas?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Yup.

Comment: What happened in 2014 to cause a drop of more than 20% in answers over 3 months?

Comment: @NotThatGuy https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320223/what-happened-to-stack-overflow-in-2014

Comment: FWIW, it's happened - as of Feb 2020 there now seem to be more new questions than new answers.

Answer (score 67):

No one is talking about it, but another issue is bounties. We need *75* rep to set a bounty which means only 8 upvotes instead of 15. The smallest amount is *50* which is also only 5 upvotes instead of 10.

Basically, it's now easier to add bounty to a question and make it featured, and it's also easier to get back the amount spent since the question is more visible, so it is more likely to get upvotes (5 upvotes are faster than 10).

In other words, featuring a question will almost cost nothing for users, so we will get more and more featured questions that are *poor*.

I guess it would be good to also revise the threshold of [the bounty privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) and maybe double the amount of bounties from `[50 - 500]` to `[100 - 1000]`.

Comment: Another valid point raised. Which also reflected by the bad quality bountied questions even before the change.

Answer (score 61):

Unfortunately, I think this will only encourage [help vampires](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/).

As I've written in my reply to the blog post - I have 16 questions and almost 3000 answers. If things were reversed, should I still have the 64K reputation I have, or should it be significantly lower?

Answer (score 47):

Upping the reputation points of questions adds to the problem of not showing the score of a question correctly.

**The problem is NOT that downvotes do not count more, but how they are shown on the question/answer.**

Downvotes are shown in Stack Overflow as the same as upvotes. The "Score" for a question or answer that has had two upvotes and four down votes shows as -2. But really, the "Score" of this question/answer is 1.2. (Calculated: (20 - 8)/10)

So many times, someone will see a question with a negative score and give them a "pity vote".  The pity vote far out weighs the downvote.  This rewards bad question asking by gaining easy reputation.

**To be clear, I don't really care how much downvotes count for (though I think they should be more), but whatever they count for needs to show in the score of the question/answer.**

On a more personal note, I ask way more questions than I answer. I recall years ago, when I was just about to break into the community moderator tools, the change was made to make a question upvote count 5 (instead of the 10 it was back then). It caused my rep to be cut almost in half.

[I felt really betrayed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42958/is-so-shooting-itself-in-the-foot).  I work hard to ask really good questions (I have 100+ Stack Overflow  gold badges related to good questions.) I felt that Stack Overflow was devaluing the extra work I put into good questions.

In the end I got over it because (as others have noted) I was still getting the reward of an answer to many of my questions.

I will happily accept the reputation boost, but I can really identify with those who feel betrayed because their answer-based reputation points just got devalued by half (compared to question-based reputation points).

Comment: Do you have a source for "*So many times, someone will see a question with a negative score and give them a "pity vote".*" ?

Comment: @Pureferret: \*raises hand\*. If I see a question at -1 that should in fairness be at 0, I tend to give it an up vote, which I wouldn't have done if it already was at 0. In these cases I don't as much want to award the question, as I want to encourage others to answer it.

Comment: @AkselA then that's not pity voting that's doing something for the community

Comment: I've done that.

Comment: @Pureferret - I've seen it done. I've seen COMMENTS statiing it's the reason for upvotes. Heck sometimes I did it myself, though not as a policy. Both on SO and smaller sites

Answer (score 42):

> ...in recognition of the fact that useful, high-quality questions are just as valuable as high-quality answers.

This is factually false. A well written question with no answers is not helpful to the vast majority of users who share the same problem. Only an answer can save them time and effort finding a solution. A good question derives the vast majority of its value from the existence of answers attached to it.

This change continues SO's trend of making decisions based on incorrect premises.

Comment: Good questions do tend to get answered so the problem of good but unanswered questions is mostly hypothetical.  When looking for duplicates, a garbage confusing question can make it a worse target.  Especially if it means answers to the real question are cluttered with addressing other problems and side-tracks so even the answers aren't a good simple answer to a single problem.  So depending on context, they can be almost as useful in the long run.

Comment: @PeterCordes It appears that only posts [bad enough to get deleted are unlikely to get an answer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1150214?opt.withExecutionPlan=true). Even 82.7% of closed questions have answers. So whether a question is good has little bearing on whether it's answered, unless you're going to assert that over 80% of closed questions are good. So the value in writing good questions is quite low. It's the *answers* that make a question valuable, and a bad question can be cleaned up later if it receives a good answer.

Comment: You misunderstood my point.  As you say, most questions get answered, and almost all good questions get answered.  The value in a good question is not just that it *has answers* (almost all questions get that) but that it makes a good place for canonical answers without a bunch of confusion that side-tracks and clutters answers.  And that it makes it easy for future readers to see if they have the same problem by clearly explaining what the question is.

Comment: Agreed that questions can be simplified and cleaned up in many cases, and the editors who do that work to make a good canonical target get no rep reward, while the original author of an originally-terrible question reaps the rep reward.  I don't support bumping question upvote rep all the way to 10.  Maybe 6 or 7, but until there's more connection between question upvote and contribution of the author to question quality 10 doesn't make sense.

Comment: @PeterCordes Even in your explanation, the value of a good question is contingent on the value of the answers it helps readers find. That is my point. Many well written but obscure questions go unanswered, but these are not particularly valuable. I'm not saying a well written question is worthless, but it's certainly not very valuable all by itself. As such, good questions are not "just as valuable" as good (or sometimes even poor) answers.

Comment: *Many well written but obscure questions go unanswered* Really?  That claim was missing from your answer which is what I was commenting about.  If they're well-written *and* on topic, questions tend to get answers eventually.  I agree with your argument that answers are what have real value to people searching, and should be rewarded with more rep.  But not all of your reasoning to support that really holds up, in my experience.  (And questions have value in helping make the site more searchable (but mostly just with useful titles which are often written by editors)

Comment: TL:DR: I don't disagree with most of your points, just the one I commented about originally.

Comment: @PeterCordes Many only because the volume of questions is so large, not as a percentage. (Because obscure questions are practically by definition uncommon.) I mention them because they do exist and because they demonstrate my overall point: that questions are inherently *less* valuable than answers, even though good ones have some value. Your mentions of good questions as a nexus for good answers further reinforces my point, that it's the answers that provide the far greater share of value. I've made an edit that may make the answer more palatable to you.

Answer (score 40):

This basically makes downvotes on questions even less useful. Questions now can have even more negative scores and still propel peoples reputation towards privileges that can impact the site quality. Why bothering to downvote on questions anymore? I don't think this will end well.

Good answers are even more valuable than good questions. That should be reflected in the rep gains. As it is now, it is kind of a regression and in my eyes, away from the optimum.

Time will tell how quality of questions will develop, but I did not have the impression that +5 rep for every upvote on a question was a problem that needed solving.

The official reasons stated, as far as I can reconstruct them from the explanations given by [Cody Gray](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/391248/1536976), are not very extensive. Much more could have been written there and the community could have been included in the process. This is unsatisfying.

Just one thing: If the observation is that decreased rep for upvotes on questions doesn't increase question quality, then one still cannot conclude without doubt that increased rep will not decrease question quality. Maybe it would have been much worse with a different rep gain.

All in all I don't like it.

Comment: _Good answers are more valuable than good questions._ Do you know what "cause and effect" means?

Comment: @scopchanov  "Do you know what "cause and effect" means?"  Yes.

Comment: Good questions help thousands of people googling the same problem. Helping more people makes good answers better, right?

Comment: @user3226167 Good questions help only indirectly via the good answers. I didn't write that good questions are without value at all.

Comment: @Trilarion I just want to point out googling is how most people use SO. They do not ask questions. Questions and answers can't be reached have no value to them. I think questions and answers helping more people should get more votes.

Comment: @user3226167 "...questions and answers helping more people should get more votes." That's definitely the case, if you correlate question and answer scores with number of visits you will get a very high correlation coefficient, I'm quite sure.

Answer (score 36):

## Thousands of points for a single sentence?

In general I agree: A good question is worth the same reward.

But I doubt the voters motivations…

– Often a vote is given by answeres, **just to trigger the OP to come back** to vote and accept their answer.
(**Remark**: In a comment jpmc26 states, that this is not true. It's just my anecdotal observation. And I even read a *tutorial* about "*how to earn reputation*" written by somebody suggesting exactly the above and one user telling in a comment, that this tip was extremly helpful. But I cannot find it at the moment...)
– Often a **very complicated question** has a lot of views, but no votes and no answers. People just don’t understand it. Someone provides a long and comprehensive answer. The OP is excited, millions of thanks, but no extra votes.
– **Most votes we find at beginner questions**. Even if the quality is low. That’s simply a mass effect
– **Many beginner questions are duplicates** but will be answered with a lot of votes (class-room round trips).
– **Most votes we find on OLD questions** with **out-dated answers**. Often enough a question is closed “as duplicate” with a link to such an old question with a really bad (outdated) accepted answer.
– We can find TOP-Users, gold-badgers at tags, who gave just 3 highly rated contributions.

What I would appreciate:

– A privilege for highly rated users, to **mark contributions as “outdated”**.
– A privilege for highly rated users, to **mark contributions as “excellent”**.
– Something like a “community-bounty”, which does not take away the user’s points (in connection with the “excellent” mark?).
– And eventually **some “fading away” of old points** (in connection with the “outdated” mark?).
– And eventually an **upper limit**. Earning 1000 points with a single contribution smells a bit.

I've spent many, many hours really *earning* my current 56k reputation on SO. This change brought ~56k reputation increase to one user who placed a trivial single-sentence question (**Look at the last example below...**) - without any effort...

## Some examples...

To state this first: **I really do NOT want to offend anybody** here!

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1196/aku) , was not active for about 8 years. This user has got more than 100k reputation with less than 500 contributions in total. He shows up at the `[tsql]` tag as **"Top-User" with just 3 answers** in total. His personal top answer has got ~2400 votes and is absolutely trivial. The question to this answer is very short and has got almost 1700 votes.

One more

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/32899/ben-noland) has got almost 30k reputation with just ~50 contributions. His best question is a trivial one liner  with more than 700 ups. His best answer is a trivial *code-only* answer worth more than 1000 ups. As the underlying question (a trivial one-liner worth almost 600 ups itself) is tagged with `[xml]`, this high answer pushes the user into the `[xml]` top user list, without even being XML related...

One more

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join/38578#38578) is absolutely trivial and has got 4.5k ups. 45k rep just with one single sentence? The user behind is settled at ~50k, so 90% of his total rep is this one single line...
The highest answer, (which is not bad!) returned 60k rep to the user.

And **really extrem**:

The question [What are the differences between git pull and git fetch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/292357/5089204) paid almost **115k**(!!!) reputation. Just **one single sentence and most trivial content**...

This cannot be the way it should be...

Comment: I disagree with your very first statement, but I've upvoted your answer since I heartily agree with almost all of the rest. I *especially* like the idea of a total reputation limit on a single post. Thank you.

Comment: @jpmc26 Thx for the backup. I just added some examples

Answer (score 34):

One thing that may have been overlooked when it was decided to recalc *retrospectively* is that [working through the lower rep ranges is actually *kind of fun*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges).

You would get a little notification, then read about your new privilege and get to try it out. And then strive towards the next one, which was always spaced a little further away than last time - a bit more of a challenge! That was probably a big part of the whole appeal of this site in the first place, and inspired people to stick around and contribute.

I'm not sure how I'd feel about being artificially "boosted" through a whole bunch of privileges suddenly like this, maybe a little bit robbed of the goal I was working towards. I just got boosted up and through 200k and, even though any new privileges are long gone, still felt a little twinge of annoyance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure The Powers That Be know about gamification and how it works. ;)

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - doubtful. Powers that be are of an ideological persuasion of "participation medals are better than earned achievements", to go on a bumper sticker level of nuance.

Answer (score 30):

Answers are worth more because they actually provide information. Questions are just shells to be filled with that information. The same question with different information each time isn't worth what the same answer with different information each time is.

People writing answers have to know or find the information they're giving. People writing questions just have to know how to convey their problem clearly.

Hey, just to let you know, I will greatly benefit from this. That doesn't mean I have to like it.

Comment: One of the main reasons why people end up asking bad questions is because they don’t realize that questions, too, must *provide information*. I do understand your larger point that there seems to be more useful information conveyed by answers, and that makes them uniquely valuable, but two things: (1) voting always has skewed heavily towards answers, and this change won’t affect that (so answerers will still end up netting more rep), and (2) questions are as necessary as answers to achieve our goal of building a library of high-quality Q&A about programming.

Comment: @CodyGray "questions are as necessary as answers" Yes, but I would say that we don't have a shortage of questions really, a shortage of answers is more likely.

Comment: @CodyGray Good questions are indeed hard to write, but a lot of those questions have only become good after substantial editing and/or discussions in comments with those knowledgeable in the field. I'm not sure those questions turn into "Community Wiki Questions" (I'm not even sure if those exist). I'm not sure this change gives the appropriate reward to the right people. In addition, the best reward someone asking a question can have is to get a useful answer.

Answer (score 26):

I think beyond the hazard of a major recalc granting sweeping permissions to vampire users, this change additionally makes it ***way easier* to game the system** for reputation.

Effectively, as long as you can consistently produce questions that gain a down-to-upvote ratio better than 5:1 you stand to farm reputation.  What on earth is the community trying to say with that?  That nobody deserves to lose reputation without more than an 83% majority vote that they've produced garbage?  And that they deserve a reward for anything better than that ludicrously low bar of achievement?

This is only going to encourage people with bad questions to keep coming back and to *not* improve their behaviour.  Why bother when you get rep no matter what?

Comment: I saw (1) a user post a question with gibberish in the body, (2) it got downvoted to -9 and closed, (3) the user came back and said they accidentally posted too soon and updated the question with a real, albeit simple, question, (4) they got 5 upvotes and multiple votes to reopen the question.  Whether or not they intended to game the system or not, they gained 32 reputation from the snafu.  :-/

Comment: When they could have posted it right on the first place and gain 50 points instead. _Sarcasm mode on_ Yep. That is a real world manipulation right there. _Sarcasm mode off_

Comment: @scopchanov The point is there's no incentive.  People can just post a bad question every day, pulling a -20/+5 and still make 10 points a day.  The worse it is, the more attention it will get, and the more rep, even if it's a really bad question.

Comment: _People can just post a bad question every day, pulling a -20/+5 and still make 10 points a day_ => _Where do the +5 come_ (on a bad question).

Comment: @scopchanov I've given up on our side discussion so I'm just going to go ahead and make the point I think you're trying to make, which appears to be expressing your belief that a 'bad' question cannot possibly accumulate *any* upvotes while remaining a bad question.  If that's your belief, then it would seem that you are well aligned to the new policy.

Comment: I wrote a response to the story told by @LittleBobbyTables, because I have failed (and I still do) to see the benefit from this particular strategy, if the goal were to harvest r.p. You gave another example, which is fundamentally different, because it doesn't involve any post imrpovement. If you expect me to share my opinion, I need to know what you think the source of those positive votes is, as I try to make no assumptions. As for the new policy, I don't know if I am well aligned with it. Though, I certainly do agree with the "good questions are as valuable as the good answers" part of it.

Answer (score 24):

### Can we see some (more) data? Is there more?

In [your linked answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391247/what-was-the-context-of-the-decision-to-lower-the-value-of-upvotes-to-a-question/391248#391248), you say it was a "data-led re-evaluation". You also imply that Meta users might care more about this data, but still don't seem to show much of the data.

You link to [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318174/why-are-there-so-many-bad-questions/358412#358412) to justify that the 5-rep-per-question-upvote decision wasn't haven't the desired effect, but this only seems to show that our question quality isn't that great currently, and there's been a decline over time (which could've been caused by any combination of so many factors). It doesn't in any way show the direct effect of the decision. It might be that the decision helped significantly and the site would've been in a much worse state without it. Also, one of the primary metrics used to define a bad question is it having a negative score - this is definitely questionable to use for evaluating this decision, since upvotes counting more would arguably not make much of a difference to questions that aren't upvoted in the first place. Askers of such questions might be motivated to try to *avoid* downvotes or bans instead of *getting* upvotes. I would expect it to make more of a difference to users that consistently get an upvote here or there to their questions, but never too many. They'd be much more motivated to try to ask better questions to increase the number of upvotes they get.

It also seems that you're aware we have too many low-quality questions, and this decision was to try to address that. Yet it seems like you were pretty rash in irrevocably reversing it and thus making possibly by far the biggest change to the site in a long time. I say "irrevocably" because of course you could just undo it, but that would greatly upset the people you were trying to appease in the first place by reverting it. This is especially true because it would take some time to get meaningful data that might tell you reverting it was a terrible idea, at which point everyone would be very much used to the new way things are.

I would agree that asking a good question is (or at least can be) hard, but I would need some evidence to believe people asking good questions care much about reputation, especially compared to people asking low-quality questions. I would also be sceptical that reputation hunters would focus on questions instead of answers (and whether they'd even be able to ask a good question), since it's generally the roll of the dice whether a question will be seen by anyone, and there's certainly an element of luck in terms of how it will be received. Not to mention that you actually need to *have* a decent question before you can ask it (a question that's just another duplicate is not decent, IMO). Although users might be more inclined to ask unusual questions to try to get to HNQ, which can seemingly be done fairly easily in some cases. You may consider this a good or bad thing. I personally consider such questions to be the scourge of the few sites I frequent, thus an increase in such questions would be quite bad, but maybe that's just me.

#### What would I like to see (or have seen)?

**Analysis of what happened following the initial decision.**

Consider:

- Total number of questions
- Total number of answers
- Average number of questions and answers per user
- Scores for questions and answers (the total, average per post and average per user)
- Other measures of quality (views, closure, deletion)
- Increases of average post score and quality for individual users over time (i.e. are subsequent questions asked by users better?)

Consider both what happened immediately, and over the next year or so. Include a detailed analysis of the data. Identify and show points in time where other changes occurred which might also affect this data.

Of course this happened during the early days, so it might not be that meaningful and all of that data might not even exist.

Although I hope to at least see the above analysis of the effect of *reverting* the decision a few months or a year from now.

**Some user study or survey to determine what motivates people to (a) ask questions and (b) take time to improve their question before asking.**

My primary motivators to ask or improve a question are getting an answer, extremely high standards, contributing to the body of knowledge that is the internet and what others think of me. Reputation is so far down in my list of concerns, it's not even funny. For answers reputation might be a more significant factor. Although that's just me, and I've just asked 6 or so questions on Stack Overflow. It's not that I know everything, it's just that I can almost always find the answer somewhere online.

**Trying to check the correlation between score and quality, instead of using score as a measure of quality.**

I would focus on those around 0 score (say +3 to -3), as highly upvoted or highly downvoted posts have a much higher chance to be correlated with the other measures of quality.

Other ways to measure quality would include whether it's closed and deleted and the number of views it gets (especially after the initial spike and those coming from search engines). Although, unfortunately, all of these are at least somewhat linked to score.

This would show you whether people are upvoting low quality posts, which would show that this change is likely to encourage more such posts, i.e. do harm.

**Check upvotes on low-quality posts.**

This is similar to the above point, but instead of looking at score, look at just upvotes.

Here you can also include score as a measure of quality, and you can also include highly downvoted posts.

This would be a stronger signal of whether people are upvoting "low quality" posts.

**Analyse other (non-SE) sites.**

I wouldn't quite know whether this is ethical, nor what you'd be willing to share publicly about any such analysis, but how other sites are getting by using certain models (at least based on what can be seen publicly) might be a decent measure of which models work and what one might expect when moving in one direction or the other. Even if there are many other differences between SE and those sites.

**Some experiments on smaller sites.**

The large number of sites on SE could be a great environment for experimentation.

Rolling this out to one or two smaller sites before doing it network-wide would provide some good data for what effects we can expect, and also make undoing it more viable.

On the other hand, having reputation work differently across different sites on the network might be questionable and confusing. Also, sites might not much appreciate being experimented on.

Answer (score 22):

A concern I don't see addressed in other answers:

**Will this result in more voting rings?**

In my opinion, this change *incentivizes* voting rings.

Consider:

**Posting a voting-ring-friendly question is more trivial than an answer**:

1. It doesn't require a relevant question that already exists.
2. It doesn't have to pass many of the flag checks (e.g. NAA) available on answers

**It doubles the reputation for questions, which are more trivial to post than answers**

Ergo, the incentive to create a voting ring is increased, while the barriers to operating have been lowered.

Comment: You raise a good point about voting rings. I'm not sure I'd go so far as to say "incentivizes", but it definitely makes voting rings easier to spin up. Fortunately, us moderators do a pretty decent job of stamping these out. We have functional tools for detecting voting rings, and we are pretty vigilant in enforcing the rules surrounding the sanctity of voting. (Among the moderators who recently resigned were some of the best in the business at dealing with vote fraud, so that's a loss we definitely feel, but we'll continue to do our best in reining these in.)

Answer (score 21):

My only issue is the obvious one: for some reason, on Stack Overflow in the last year or so, a lot of poor-quality questions seem to attract an immediate upvote. I can't explain why this has started happening—and perhaps I'm just imagining it—but this new change will obviously lead to disproportionate rewards for users asking such questions.

I still support the proposal, despite the above misgivings. Rewarding even extremely poor-quality questions will encourage more investment in Stack Overflow by the askers, hopefully ultimately resulting in better questions.

*... Four Years Later (intoned by the SpongeBob narrator)...*

I don't know what I was thinking but the previous paragraph is nonsense. Rewarding low quality questions just results in more low quality questions.

Comment: *"Rewarding even s##t questions will encourage more investment in SO by the askers, hopefully ultimately resulting in better questions."* -- hrmm, that's a real slippery slope of an argument.

Comment: This has been the case for as long as SO has existed, reenforced by the fact that you earn the ability to upvote first and all of the wording around downvotes discourages you from using them.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: I might call it wishful thinking.

Comment: I see this too and the effect now will be that bad question getting upvotes is an even more attractive thing. Just pose your bad question because it will generate rep anyway. We may think this move increases the signal, but instead it may just increase noise.

Comment: FWIW, I mentioned a couple of reasons why low quality answers may get upvotes [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390907/we-need-better-tools-to-prevent-long-tail-of-crap-on-popular-questions/390999#390999), some of those reasons apply to questions too.

Comment: @PM2Ring: Some of them are relevant, but I'm seeing shi....err... very poor-quality questions only a few minutes old getting an upvote.

Comment: Understood. IME, it mainly happens on homework questions, so I assume it's school friends upvoting each other's posts (and as I said in that answer, they possibly don't even realise they are doing anything wrong). If a few friends are studying together, and they're stuck on their homework, one posts a question, the others upvote it, and they all get the benefit of the answers.

Answer (score 21):

Why only ten?

A good, non-duplicate, on-topic, following the guidelines question is such a rare sight, that in my eyes it is worth a hundred points. No sarcasm.

For me, asking a question is a helluva job. I spend from 30 minutes to several hours in preparations, googling, trying found answers, googling, gathering evidence, googling, double-checking premises, googling, hunting down human errors, googling, creating an MCVE, and googling again. As a result, most questions remain unasked or hastily deleted. Given a question asked with such an effort, with an answer that would serve the community, ten points/vote is too small. We should reward such questions much more.

However. Most questions asked on Stack Overflow do not follow that painful routine. As a matter of fact, most questions a programmer could ask the community are duplicates by definition. Therefore, the voting system should encourage the knowledge reuse, not starting new posts. Imagine Wikipedia rewarding creation of new articles that duplicate existing ones. Imagine Wikipedia that has hundreds of thousands articles on the same topic? That's Stack Overflow.

And now we want to encourage the creation of duplicated articles even more.

Comment: Implementing bounty system for rewarding good questions seems like better solution than rewarding just about everything.

Comment: Re *"encourage the knowledge reuse, not starting new posts"*: Indeed it should. Unfortunately, the system is only optimised (gamified) for providing very quick answers to (new) questions. We are now at 18,565,521 questions.

Answer (score 19):

I don't overestimate the value of internet points, but they do have some value. If they didn't, no one would want to do anything to get more of them. The premise of Stack Overflow is gamification.

From some material quoted in [one of Jeff Atwood's blog posts](https://blog.codinghorror.com/for-a-bit-of-colored-ribbon/)

> What we saw as our membership scrabbled over valueless points was that there didn't actually need to be any sort of material reward other than the points themselves. We didn't need to allow them to trade the points in for benefits, virtual or otherwise. It was enough of a reward for most people just to see their points wobble upwards.

We shouldn't care that a whole ton of extra points are suddenly thrown around. We shouldn't care that in many new cases questions will be worth more points than their answers. So what? They don't mean anything. But by that same logic, we shouldn't have cared about earning points with our answers in the first place.

This change isn't horrible (or at least I'm not in a hurry to jump to that conclusion.) Like many, I don't have really strong feelings about it. But to whatever extent points did represent knowledge or expertise (factoring in that there were already points for questions) they will represent it a little less.

Another reason why it feels a bit wrong is the timing. Stack Exchange has damaged their reputation by engaging in what many consider unethical behavior aimed at members of their own community. Aside from that they've shown an interest in improving their reputation. It feels like they're trying to minimize the harm and just make friends by printing a whole ton of those points we work for. Giving something away devalues it. Giving it away to create a more favorable impression of the company makes it sting.

It feels small saying that. They're just meaningless internet points. I also answer questions just because I like helping people. Reading and answering questions has benefited me in many significant ways. Perhaps that's why I don't feel more strongly. But even if the value is arbitrary, it motivates people, and this makes that value a little bit cheaper.

Comment: Well, not entirely useless. Enough reputation = privileges. All depends on what people who gain privileges *do* with them, of course...

Comment: It was once sold as a way to easily be hired (it is after all a single number that a machine can easily process). But HR persons  and recruiters probably very quickly realised that it was being gamed.

Comment: @PeterMortensen - It still carries some weight. If you've got some rep potential employers pay some attention. They'll at least look at your answers.

Comment: @CindyMeister - Many of what we call "privileges" are just extra ways to donate time to the site. I'm not saying that's bad, but it's a weird sort of privilege. Getting to relax in airline lounge because you have lots of miles is a privilege. Getting to be the flight attendant and walk around telling people to put their seats in the upright position, not so much. (Getting to fly the plane would be cool.)

Comment: what's horrible is that it is applied **retroactively**. *that* is truly horrible. IMO. and they didn't just change the final value. they changed the whole *history* of your rep (at https://stackexchange.com/users/NNN/name?tab=reputation). truly Orwellian.

Comment: @Scott Hannen: You are correct. [A real-world example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ULtPvIsaRU&t=10m3s) from a few years back (reputation points actually used as a filter): *"GitLab ... because I did not have enough points on Stack Overflow, they told me 'no'."* It is no wonder voting rings exist.

Answer (score 17):

This is about 9 years overdue, and I'm happy for that; but there are a lot more pressing issues to fix first, not the least of which is rebuilding the trust between the community, the moderators, and the company.

If Stack Overflow was publicly working to rebuild trust, I'd be glad to give them kudos on this; but right now this is coming across as a deflection from the problems we are encountering -- a way to mollify us without actually addressing the underlying issues.

Comment: Rebuild trust by avoiding any discussion *a priori* ? Rebuild trust by pretending the problem is the whistle-blower and not the decisions made behind walls ? Rebuild trust by ignoring the departure and complaints of users hit with floods of identical bad questions ? Rebuild trust by breaking the contract which made us answer, that is that "reputation" was also a measure of problem solving ability and technical knowledge and had some kind of value ? This is not rebuilding trust, it's just definitely killing it.

Comment: I completely understand the sentiment here, and have had similar feelings myself. A couple of things to keep in mind, just as devil's advocate. First, although staff didn't discuss this with the community at large, they *did* share it with moderators in private channels, and they *did* listen to our feedback. What was announced today is not the same as what was originally drafted. That's a huge step forward, so it deserves recognition. Second, the lower-level staff who is responsible for implementing the day-to-day business of Q&A is not the same staff who has the authority to rebuild trust.

Comment: It's not coming off as a _deflection_ in the process of rebuilding trust to me. It feels like twisting the knife. This was not discussed with the community, not what the community wanted (per [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337843/369403)), and not what it needed.

Comment: @CodyGray "Second, the lower-level staff who is responsible for implementing the day-to-day business of Q&A is not the same staff who has the authority to rebuild trust." - while I feel this is true, it certainly doesn't help that Sara is the one to make this blog. At this point, there's clear negative sentiment built up based on her involvement with pronoun-gate and fallout. Thus by posting this blog it feels like complete disregard of the aforementioned more pressing issues.

Comment: @DenysSéguret That's exactly the sentiment that me and probably a lot of other users are having right now. You should really post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I tried to make an answer of the main point

Comment: Hey, people who are downvoting: Read the whole thing. It's not all evil.

Comment: @JL2210, yes, but we can't split our votes between the first and second paragraphs. Both paragraphs are relevant, but I voted on the paragraph that's more relevant.

Comment: @ScottHannen Most of the first paragraph is even saying *not now*.

Comment: "What was announced today is not the same as what was originally drafted. That's a huge step forward" Saddest thing I've heard in 2019

Comment: @Mysticial It's more the fact that she is demonstrably an ideologue who rejects the premises upon which SO was built (particularly the premises of valuing your dedicated users, treating them with respect even if you disagree with them, and prioritizing content quality over personal feelings). Given how different her views are, it's not clear why she would want to work at SO, other than to use its success as a starting point for her own ideal rather than start fresh somewhere else. Some people earn your trust with the pattern of their actions, and others lose it. Sara is in the latter category.

Answer (score 15):

I would be *super* curious to know if there is any downward trend in questions receiving upvotes after this change.

I've been lurking on the "Newest" tab since this was announced, and I really feel like the number of people upvoting has gone down noticeably.  It could just be confirmation bias, but I feel like people are being even stingier with their upvotes.

Comment: Heh. Well, that certainly would be an ironic side-effect. That data should be accessible from SEDE after a couple of weeks.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables I've certainly been freer with my downvotes since the change (since they count for some much less now). That's not quite the effect you suggest out, but similarly I suspect it isn't the effect they're after.

Answer (score 15):

Re-iterating what so many others have said:

This is a horrible move. It enables [help vampires](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/) (and notoric bad-question-askers in general) and devalues the work of people who **contribute** by answering questions.

Secondly, it is yet another "who cares what the community feels" move. Community feedback - bah! ***[L’État, c’est moi!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_French_expressions_in_English#E)***

Personally, I've had enough. Starting today I'll cease all contributions to the Stack Exchange network - no more reviewing, no more edits, no more flagging, **no more answers**. If I need to ask a question to help **myself**, sure I'll do that (and hey, I'll get 10 rep per upvote), but that's it.

Answer (score 14):

I do not really mind the change per se, but it comes with problems attached.

1. This has never been debated with the community, and it seems like yet another attack against the community, this time without even the pretense of debate (unless you count some meta post from 2010). 
   Look. I get it, everybody is complaining nowadays, things are tense, SE is a company and they can do what they want, etc. etc. 
   But why are they pushing so much to alienate their user base, and is there any purpose to this change other than *panem et circenses* to celebrate the new CEO?
2. What about horrible "historical" questions that can't be nuked out of existence because the answers are still great? Those gathered quite a lot of upvotes. Do the askers really deserve a reputation bump? I keep hearing "vote content not people" and duh-uh, I get it. But that content is still bad and does not deserve a double reputation for upvotes. That is *one* example of problems I can think of.

The [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338135/what-to-do-concretely-about-the-new-every-question-asker-gets-more-reputation-r/) I asked in meta was not well received overall, and I might have had better luck on meta SO, but TL;DR, I think this is damaging in terms of relationships between SE and the user base, and may also have some potential damage on how the sites work (especially SO) - seemingly nobody cared to investigate before hand.

Comment: What are some examples of horrible "historical" questions?

Comment: @PeterMortensen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)'s one, top of my head.

Comment: @PeterMortensen to be excruciatingly clear: the answers are great. The Q&A *does* have value (at the very least because it's a dupe magnet for similar, crappy questions). But is the reputation bonus deserved for the original asker? No way.

Answer (score 13):

This could be a good opportunity to increase the reputation "weight" of downvotes from 2 to a [larger number](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/356164/509868), which some people want.

Since you probably want to do all changes to reputation retroactively (presumably for technical reasons of database query performance), many people would be dissatisfied with such a change. But together with a massive increase in "free" reputation points on questions, such a change would be much less painful, to the point where you could actually implement it, and ignore the 0.1% of users who would lose some reputation points.

However, now any hope for such a change is lost. Did anyone think about the downvote-change opportunity when doing the upvote-change? I found no mention of this consideration, so probably not. Was it possible? Certainly, if only such a change were announced for the community to discuss.

Comment: I don't know if it was considered by the team, but I agree with you that it probably was not.  However, there are [some compelling reasons *not* to increase the weight of downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/42763/153008).

Comment: I'm trying not to comment on this because I'm just nitpicking. What's shocking isn't the decision, but what wasn't even considered. This is portrayed as something that they thought through carefully over a period of time. How would something like this not even come up for consideration? How did no one even think about testing it first to see what the impact would be before making a large announcement and practically irreversible change? It gives the impression that the goal was just to dump lots of points and nothing else was even worth thinking about.

Answer (score 12):

The answer I gave on Robert's post on the network-wide meta still stands: If a question has more than X times the number of downvotes than upvotes (where X is 2; possibly less) and a minimum of Y downvotes (probably 2), **it is a bad question**. The user should not be able to net positive rep through pity upvotes.

If anything, this is going to make experienced users throw around more downvotes to "balance things out," which will make new posters feel worse when their questions have a net negative score.

SE should consider lowering the amount of upvote points given if a post is closed as off topic, or is a "bad question" (as defined above). This is coming from someone whose only question upvotes are on an offtopic question.

The other fear I have is that the edit privilege (both suggest and full) is now given out more easily. There are so many asinine edits that get approved that really should be rejected. By making it overall easier to get rep, we're going to have way more crap bumping to the front page.

Comment: I wanted to suggest similar idea for scaling, maybe questions that get 5 votes (in proportion to down votes) get scaled up and are worth 10 instead of 5. I'm not really sure how a system like that would work, or if it's even a good idea but could alleviate the concerns while rewarding good questions and not rewarding bad ones. But maybe the answer isn't a clear cut static value for a vote?

Answer (score 12):

I believe that this change is a bad idea, at least according to my understanding of reputation points on Stack Overflow.

I personally gained some rep in this change, but since I usually mostly post answers, the overall feeling I got is that the relevance of my reputation points decreased. This is a pity because I always thought of my rep. points as **something that would be relevant when looking for a job** (through Stack Overflow jobs or elsewhere).

But it seems that the underlying issue is basically the disagreement on the actual answer to this question:

## What do reputation points represent on Stack Exchange?

#### 1. Metric of trustworthiness and expertise

If reputation points are a **metric of user trustworthiness and expertise**, then I would argue that the weight of question upvotes could be reduced to even more, without affecting the *correlation* between user reputation and expertise.

Objectively, "experts" are people who have lots of **answer** upvotes. That's why sites like [Experts-Exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experts-Exchange) will require their customers to pay to get **answers**, and don't consider paying these same customers for asking a "great and useful question".

-- or --

#### 2. Metric of contribution to the site/community/world knowledge

This is an entirely different thing, but one that is far harder to define IMHO.

Yes, a question like *"how do I commit something using Git"* will get tons of traffic to Stack Overflow. Yes, **answers** to this question will help millions of people. Yes, these answers wouldn't have existed if this question was never asked.

However, in this case, I would still argue that contribution through these questions is rather "accidental".

- If a person wanted to learn about "committing to Git" in 2009, this person will be considered a great contributor 10 years later. Even if the wording in this question was initially crap, but got salvaged by other users into something reasonable, the asker will be considered a great contributor.
- If a person wanted to know about "committing to Git" in 2019, this person will be heavily downvoted for not taking 5 minutes of their time and googling for a result.
- At the same time, a person with a really hard problem, who might have spent hours in preparing the question, will get fewer upvotes and probably drive less traffic into the site.

So the contribution of asking a question (and I have personally asked a couple of questions which got a bunch of upvotes) is to essentially serve as a bunch of SEO-friendly keywords for driving traffic into Stack Overflow.

---

It's obvious that driving traffic is a good thing. People have daily jobs maintaining this site. It's running reliably 24/7 and both the hardware and the software need maintenance.

But I strongly believe that rewarding users for bringing more people to the site does not have a positive effect of the **quality of this site**.

Comment: Didn't [the hyphen site](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experts-Exchange) get [the memo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jsLUidiYm0w) approx. 10 years in and no longer require payment? I can't find the reference now.

Comment: @PeterMortensen: I believe [their business model hasn't changed much](https://www.experts-exchange.com/plansAndPricing.jsp).

Answer (score 11):

I think generally it's a neutral change - I don't see a huge benefit but I'm not sure it's a huge problem. I have two small concerns:

- The low end reputation thresholds. Given that a lot of people will be reaching these quicker the impact should at least be considered. I'm mostly concerned about the ability to upvote, which will both make voting rings a bit easier to set up, and (less nefariously) lead to people who don't yet understand the community standards being upvoted more.
- Bounties will become quite unbalanced. My experience is that voting voting on bounty questions is pretty indiscriminate with little regard for the quality (or on-topicness) of the question. I've also often found that bounty questions are more upvoted than the answers on them (probably mostly because the answers don't exist for the whole life of the bounty.

  Under the 5-rep system, my (anecdotal) impression was that a bounty question typically recovered 2/3 of the reputation in upvotes. Under the 10-rep system I suspect bounties will provide free rep and mostly serve to reward the asker. Given the idea of a bounty is "sacrifice some rep for exposure" this seems counterintuitive if there's no sacrifice. Maybe now would be a good time to kill off bounties?

---

A secondary point: in [the justifications for this change](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/391248/4657412) you make the point that various changes to the system (beyond "amount of rep") help limit bad questions. Perhaps now would be a good time to bring forward the "3-votes to close" change that was trialled. A lot of the issues people have with this are about overall rewarding bad questions with (say) 3 downvotes and 1 sympathy upvote. If such questions could be reliably and quickly disposed of then that issue would go away.

---

A final quick edited in tertiary point: there was a comment from @shoq that I can't find right now on the initial 10->5 vote change ages ago that said something like: it's quite common to have a bad question, edited into something more acceptable, and the upvotes are rewarding the asker for the editors' work. I think that still applies (and would tend to apply less to answers, where the answerer has at least contributed a solution even if it's badly written).

Comment: *"Perhaps now would be a good time to bring forward the "3-votes to close" change that was trialled."* Absolutely! I am *hugely* in favor of this; always have been. My sources tell me that there is a good chance that may be introduced as a permanent feature. Along the same lines, another thing I desperately want is to expand the franchise to gold badge holders, and possibly even silver-badge holders. Gold badge holders in a tag should be able to instantly close a question for *any* of the off-topic, too broad, or unclear reasons. Same for a single silver-badge holder plus one other user.

Answer (score 11):

How will this affect old, historic questions that no longer meet current SO standards? It seems unfair that a historic question that doesn't meet today's standard with 100+ upvotes gets such a huge rep boost vs. new users asking similar questions that gets closed/downvoted?

At first this seemed a good change, but, the more I think about those old questions, the less I'm convinced...

Comment: Someone else might correct me on this, but the rep recalculation still takes into account the 200 rep cap daily. So if someone earned 30 upvotes on questions in a day, instead of 150 rep they get 200 (hitting cap). Most old questions with votes coming at a rate that never approached cap would likely be near a flat double.

Comment: @Unihedron ahh that is slightly better than! Still .. scary if the latter applies more so than not

Comment: Historic questions that don't meet today's standards can and should have historical locks applied to them. This will prevent any future voting. Unfortunately, there is another policy that was introduced (and largely celebrated by the community) that complicates this: you get to keep the reputation you earned for historical posts, even if those posts are deleted or locked. This sidesteps a lot of whining about content curation, but is clearly a double-edged sword. On the other hand, rep was never a perfect metric in the first place, and even with +5 rep, users were still making bank off these.

Comment: @CodyGray ah that makes sense, hopefully one day I'll get the rep priv. and start locking :)

Comment: Historical locks are a moderator-only feature. If you come across a closed question that you think should be locked, you can raise a flag or talk to a moderator. Note that locks are only used on historical Q&A that add significant value, such that deleting them would be making the Internet a worse place. For all other old posts that do not meet our current standards, we just *delete* (which is a privilege granted by rep).

Comment: @CodyGray That makes more sense :p haha Ok will do - ty

Answer (score 11):

Answers are the only reward that matters to questions asked in good faith. An issue that hasn't been addressed is that of those that do not bother to accept and upvote answers to questions they've asked.

> As with far too many events of late, this change has been accompanied
>   by a fair amount of drama.

This drama is caused by inept community management by SO. Arbitrary decrees imposed upon communities are rarely well received. Tone deaf engagement and haughty insouciance compounds matters.

> Feedback from those who cannot comply with this requirement is subject
>   to removal.

Q.E.D.

Comment: The final quoted statement doesn't demonstrate anything of the sort you're trying to make it. We've *always* had a policy that feedback must be constructive and respectful. It used to be very clearly stated in the Code of Conduct as "be nice"; I still stand by that expectation, and interpret the CoC accordingly. Those who know me well know I am a firm believer in *light* moderation on Meta. I do not believe in censoring opinions, and I will *only* remove answers on the basis of either complete irrelevance or irredeemable offensiveness. The statement is really just a reminder, and fair warning.

Comment: @CodyGray Perhaps I should have expanded the quote: the requirements were constructive **and** respectful. This is a flag that people cannot air their true feelings if they don't like a change becuase the company is unwilling to listen to criticism and in fact wants to censor it.

Comment: @CodyGray I should add that I'm not making a judgement about you. I've not had any interactions with you other than this to do so. The statement is about the corporate actions, which I'm aware individuals are under pressure to comply with, often against their will.

Comment: Yeah, I get that you’re frustrated with the way the company has handled things lately, including both ignoring and even actively suppressing criticism. Me too. So I’m sensitive to suggestions that I might be doing that. I was sensitive before, but now I’m extra careful. So I just want to clarify that “constructive and respectful” as it appears in the announcement above is *not* a dog-whistle for “toe the company line”. I think the comments and answers here stand testament to that. It literally just means don’t attack individuals or be a jerk. Everyone’s done well following it; much appreciated

Comment: @CodyGray I don't think they are so much following it as it just being their normal mode of operation. People who contribute to SO are much nicer than the corporate statements and policies paint them out to be. There is danger that these policies are generating the issues they are purported to solve. For instance, the bar for a question upvote is much higher for me now given the increased score it confers.

Answer (score 9):

As the changes were rolled out for reputation increase, my opinion on this is instead of giving +10 on upvote we might've given +5 on answer accept.

This way the question asker, if it is a new user, won't cross the initial privileges too early and also the question will fulfill its role that it was the post which can be answerable and acceptable as well.

The above is just my opinion on it.

Comment: This will only result with accepting poor answers or answers that are not proper solutions. I have already seen plenty of cases where OP to counteract downvotes would accept just about anything to get two extra points. I can only imagine this behavior getting worse if your proposal would be implemented.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar if op has to counteract the downvote they will delete their post it is much more sensible than just to earn 2 rep on -10 rep even if op accept the poor answer the community member can still downvote that post and I don't think any sensible user will write a poor answer or answer an poor question and can get locked to delete the post which is now an acceptable answer and attract the wrath of community. that would be self destruct.

Comment: If question has upvoted answer or multiple answers it cannot be deleted by the OP.  So accepting any answer is better than nothing. With your proposal instead of +2 rep such question can gain much more reputation just by accepting the answer. Poor questions with accepted answers are harder to remove - they need much more actions from people that have moderating powers. So, again, your proposal is not a good one.

Comment: Accepted answer also cannot be deleted by the answerer so answerer is sticking their neck, no questioner will not gain more than 5rep by accepting in any circumstance if it is poor post it will only gain downvotes and close votes but nonetheless it is better than some random upvote of some user who had half read the post than to acceptance of an answerer who had taken time by considering all the risk.

Answer (score 7):

I think the *real* problem of the scoring system is that it has failed to adjust itself to the shifting nature of the questions asked on Stack Overflow.

Take the *[What and where are the stack and heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap)* question for example. It was asked more than 10 years ago, was upvoted 7841 times, starred 4664 times and awarded 58K to the person who offered the best answer. Impressive. And logical, too. It was a question about a subject in computer programming that every single programmer is aware of and is interested in.

Nevertheless, such questions (i.e. about core computer programming concepts such as the basic algorithmic structures, conditionals, loops etc) have all been asked and answered long ago; And for every programming language known to man, too!

On the contrary, try to answer one of the questions asked on SO nowadays. Most of the time, you are required to have knowledge of a very specific **combination** of programming language, code library, component framework and middleware just to come up with the easiest of answers. Good luck with that. Many of these questions are nearly impossible to answer if you're not a member of the team working with the exact set of tools and configuration as the OP (Welcome SO Teams!).

What does it mean as far as the scoring system is concerned?

It means that while questions are getting considerably harder to answer, accepted answers are quite unlikely to earn a good number of upvotes because the questions themselves are of interest to very few people: the OP and his team members, if any. It is a lose-lose situation for both the questions and the answers.

Bottom line is SO needs to dig deeper and take ground-breaking decisions so as to become attractive to its new (and old) members once again.

Answer (score 7):

## Validation vs. Gamification

Points on Stack Overflow have two distinct uses. The first is the gamification experience. Points give us motivation to ask or answer questions, and reward us for that.
The second aspect is validation. Points should be a mean for validation, and high reputation should be a measure of reliability. A user with a high reputation should be someone who is more likely to be reliable in communicating code solutions, and therefor could be trusted by the community in this aspect.

The problem with this decision is that it reduces the value of good answers.
While a highly voted answer to a question is one that stands out and competes with other answers, questions are voted on a "me too" basis.

I think validation/reliability aspect of points has got a hit by this decision.

## Changing rules retroactively

Perhaps Stack Overflow would like votes for questions to be based on their quality, and not a "me too" basis, which can justify this change. The main problem is that votes up to know were made on the basis of a different virtual contract, in which votes for questions are worth 5 points, and such a consideration was not presented. This retroactive change is kind of a violation of trust and contract.

However, there is another problematic aspect. The basic rules of Stack Overflow as a platform dictate that questions compete by their topic, not by their quality. Once someone posts a poorly written question on a relevant topic, another person can't write a better quality question on the same topic. This would be considered a duplication. As often done, the only solution is to edit the low quality question of the OP. Now users who posted a poor quality question can gain lots of reputation. Validation/reliability of points/reputation has decreased.

Comment: Yes, I think it's part of the goal (and straightforward in Management's post) that they indeed are devaluing answering *in relation to* asking. It's a decision they made, they value both as much.

Answer (score 6):

> "When you're hungry, eat!" --Monkey D. Luffy

If I want to ask, I would; it doesn't matter whether you reward me or not. People have jobs/hobbies/etc and they amount (as per me) to them more than rep. points on SO.
If they gotta ask they will.

Will increasing reputation reward have any effect on the frequency of "ORGANIC" questions?

**NO** - people will ask when they want to ask, when they have a problem that they think could be solved on SO

Of course you will increase the overall frequency of questions on SO once you bring in this new change
but those "extra" questions will be nothing more than fabrications/googled/self-invented questions from people with a lots of free time on their hands. Most of these questions, no matter how good, will have a very minor real-world use because those having any real-world implications must already have been asked.

All along I have assumed your main motive behind this new change was to make people post more questions on the site, so this answer applies to that part only.

Regarding the real value of a question vs an answer - an answer is definitely more valuable as it keeps evolving over time, a question on the other hand is somewhat static.

Answer (score 3):

I don’t think this is a bad change. It was cheap to implement, and the reasoning for the rewards being set the way they were are not particularly convincing, either.

My only misgivings are:

- While not inherently bad, it is also unclear to me what we gain by making this change, or what were we losing before.
- Side effects:

  - Many users will achieve the upvote privilege sooner. It follows that there will be more upvotes around. Upvotes are nice, but they can make deleting poor content harder, which is key to curation efforts.
  - Recouping the cost for a bounty will be much easier. Bounties work because they are scare. If they are too easily recovered, these will be much more abundant (not only diluting their importance, but further strengthening the reputation-inflation feedback).
  - This could impact the question-ban process. While the algorithm is secret, reputation itself may play a role. I haven't seen question get tripped by the q-ban after they reach certain reputation thresholds, no matter how many poor (and poorly received) questions they post.
  - Etc.

Comment: [The bottom portion of this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/391248) goes into detail about what we were losing before, under the old question scoring system. A hopeful solution was introduced in 2010 to the already-recognized problem of the proliferation of low-quality questions. However, it failed to solve the problem, and actually compounded it in other ways. Since then, we've found better ways to address (although, unfortunately, not yet solve) the problem, so there's really no reason to keep the failed attempt around as policy.

Comment: Side effects are a very real concern. It's hard to run the numbers ahead of time because the rep system on this site is rather complicated (daily caps, etc.), but there will be *lots* of people gaining substantial amounts of rep, enough to, as you said, cause them to earn new privileges. I'm not sure that this will have noticeable effects, though. Upvotes already *vastly* exceeded downvotes, and DVs are still free. The bigger issue is that the recent mass exodus of quality-minded users has led to a *sharp* decline in DVs over the past month. That consequences of that will get blamed on this...

Comment: @CodyGray - so the effects are unpredictable, SO had the option to try it and see what happens, but instead decided to start with a huge, irreversible change. From that perspective this looks 10,000x worse.

Comment: @CodyGray Sorry, but why isn't that answer part of the blog post? Or at least why isn't there a link to that answer? You shouldn't need to comment with this link. IMHO the biggest problem in the recent events is/was that (most of) the staff of SE Inc. does insufficient communication. [I know, you are not SE Inc. staff so please don't feel offended by this comment]

Comment: @CodyGray The "mass exodus of quality-minded users" is literally because SE keeps making decisions like this, with very little consideration for the community. So yes, we can blame the sharp decline of downvotes on this (and all the other recent changes)

Comment: @Ocaso I'm a community-elected moderator, not a staff member. They don't let me write blog posts on the official blog. I agree the rationale should have been in there, and the company should be doing a better job of explaining themselves to veteran users. I'm doing what I can to bridge that gap.

Comment: @CodyGray I know that and I know that you are doing great work. Thanks a lot for your work!

Comment: @Jesse, the "mass exodus of quality-minded users" is the *desired* effect. The pronoun "we" has been banned from SE and these people are not welcome anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Is the real reason behind this change to increase the number of people able to moderate the sites (network wide)?

You say in your post:

> The biggest immediate change will be a substantial increase in user reputation scores, and thus an **increase in the number of users having certain privileges**. (emphasis added)

Seems like this isn't a happy accident and more like the true intention. It is no secret that there has been a decrease in moderator activity.

Comment: There hasn't been a decrease in moderator activity, I still regularly see mods doing their work. Theres a decrease in moderators and I find it unlikely that there will be many candidates at the next election

Comment: No, this is not the real reason. I say what you quoted b/c that is my practical assessment of the most significant effect that the recalculation will have. But that was not the motivation behind the change. The motivation was to address the disproportionality between askers and answerers, recognizing that [the original tactic of reducing question rep gain didn't solve the problem of low-quality questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/391248). These changes have been in the works for a very long time and genuinely have nothing to do with recent events motivating an exodus of trusted users.

Comment: Furthermore, as I say in [a comment to a similar answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/391253), this just wouldn't work, even if it were the intention. Giving a bunch of folks more reputation isn't going to do bupkis for the moderation gap. The tools don't do any good if people aren't actually using them.

Answer (score 2):

I've upvoted a number of the other answers already. I'm in agreement with the criticisms they level.

Further, the aspect of this that makes the ***least*** sense to me is retrospective recalculation — I made my upvote/downvote decisions based on one set of weights.  Now those decisions will be represented as if I had evaluated them differently.

This is akin to recalculating the score of a sporting event as if the players had taken the same actions but been playing a completely different game.  That might be an interesting exercise.  But it probably doesn't appeal to fans of the actual game.

I don't care about this change nearly as much as I care about having Stack Overflow as a useful resource.

And because that's what I care about this change only adds to the late unpleasantness.

SO, fix your stuff.

Please.

Comment: You should *not* make voting decisions based upon weight or the presence of existing votes. Instead, you should be voting based on your assessment of the usefulness and/or correctness of the post. If you thought the question was valuable, then you upvoted it; if you thought it was not (because it showed no research effort, didn't make sense, or was otherwise not useful), then you downvoted it. Because we later change the weight of those votes does not have any effect on the core judgement there, the value of the post. For more on why it's retroactive, see [Mark's excellent answer](/a/391322).

Comment: Actually, I __should__ make voting decisions according to my own criteria and not yours. This has a good deal to do with what it actually means to vote—in any context. If a vote has a consequence then I think it ought to be considered. One of the consequences of this silly vote are these silly numbers which this change makes even sillier. Yes, changing the weight has an effect on the core judgement. You’re calling for the core judgment to be a series of simplistic bijections when __in fact__ they will be reported with a (apparently capricious) weight. I prefer my votes not contradict reality.

Comment: OP solicited feedback and mine has been given. I rarely comment on meta. As I said above I care very little about this change per se. As one of the vast sea of eyeballs whose attention SE sells for a living I can only tell the company this — keep doing things the way you’re doing them and you’ll have less of my attention to sell. I doubt I’m alone. But I hope it works out. Best.

Comment: A relevant MSE post: [Today's change has retroactively changed the meaning of our past votes. Should we be able to change them?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338155/todays-change-has-retroactively-changed-the-meaning-of-our-past-votes-should-w) (I make the case for "no", similar to what Cody says, in [my answer there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/338158/335251).)

Answer (score 1):

I'll run the risk of getting hammered, and share my opinion. I think it's both great and also unimportant, or at least, less significant than everyone is making it out to be.

I read above that the reward for asking a question is getting an answer, and I agree with that. But, questions are what bring people to the site and without questions, there'd be no answers. That's not to say I think answers are less valuable, or second class citizens though. Exceptional questions deserve exceptional rewards, as do answers.

Should basic homework questions should be rewarded? No, of course not and that is why we have the power to vote on the quality of the questions. Increasing rep points won't change this, we have always had homework type questions and will continue to do so in the future.

I believe I have contributed fairly to SO over the years but rewarded unfairly in some cases. A few of my questions have allowed users to gain hundreds, if not thousands of rep points and so if we put value into reputation, then at some point the reward system becomes disproportional in favor of answers. An exceptional answer to a basic question won't get the reward it deserves either.

I've also worked hard on an answer, only to be overshadowed by a more significant user who receives up-votes just because of who he is.

Both questions and answers require hard work, but may not be rewarded equally/fairly.

Let's focus for a minute on other SO network sites though, like Movies & TV. I've been a contributor since it was a proposal on Area 51, when questions were super critical to the survival of the site. I worked hard asking good questions with a focus on quality as well as relevance to a broader audience working to get the site a spot in the list, to prove it was worth promoting. Shouldn't that mean something? Maybe it does, maybe my reward for that effort is a site that I can enjoy and ask my questions and share my knowledge.

I also spent a good effort finding unanswered questions and doing my best to provide answers because a site with a lot of unanswered questions isn't any better than a site with no questions at all.

My point is, questions and answers are equally important in their own ways. Maybe this is  a skewed point of view towards newer/smaller SO sites, but I have seen the system working on SO as bad questions get down voted and closed, duplicates are found and edits are made to improve the quality of questions, and increasing the value of a vote won't change that.

Edit: I forgot to address the retro update, but thinking about it, I don't have an opinion for or against; I'm still on the fence.

Comment: Hi @dustin-davis, I will probably be hammered for that but I think good questions are part of the deal for any site. With good questions, can you only have good answers.

Answer (score -2):

**Has anyone considered increasing to +7 or +8, not all the way to +10?**  There's no obvious reason why a question upvote *should* be equal to an answer vote, especially given the different reasons questions get upvoted which aren't dependent on quality.

Is increasing question rep going to encourage people to spend more time formulating their questions better?  Maybe for some people.

---

A separate problem is that most question upvotes are based on the subject matter of the question, not whether it's well-crafted or not.  And old questions with useful answers are often edited into shape by other people, with the original asker getting the benefit of the rep.

In the overall scheme of things, a good and highly upvoted question with canonical answers is what we want, but the system doesn't reward everyone who contributes to that.

Well-written questions are valuable as duplicate targets and as clear explanations of a problem (making it possible for people to quickly tell if their problem is the *same* problem).  Possibly this rep change will help with that, even if it has a side-effect of rewarding a lot of users who don't deserve it.

Bad questions will get asked regardless of rep, so we'll always have to filter that out.  The end goal of SO is to have good Q&As, and the gamification helps but doesn't always match perfectly with effort / contribution toward making that happen.  It's not necessary for that to be the case, but closer is better for rep to have any "meaning" to people as a measure of their contribution or their knowledge in various tags.

I don't think +10 makes sense but +7 or +8 would be ok.  Still an acknowledgement that answers require more knowledge of the subject matter, while writing good questions requires some, and basic knowledge of MCVE / debugging procedures and writing skill.

Answer (score -4):

Huh...? Yeah... Maybe it's a bad nightmare coming true. First finding the right track and morale in 2010 and then suddenly losing all of it about a decade later to just bring in more Internet traffic and a lot more garbage to the platform.

Comment: Perhaps you could expand on how you think this change is going to either "bring in more internet traffic" and/or "a lot more garbage to the platform"? There's a fundamental assumption being made here, namely that the reputation system attracts traffic, but I'm not sure that is the case.

Answer (score -6):

Almost all the responses here are from experienced question answerers rather than askers. As one of the latter, here is my perspective.

I am far from a professional programmer, but I do put a lot of thought into my questions. Nothing is more disheartening than a downvote. There have been times when I avoided asking a question for fear it would drain my reputation. Now, I can ask my questions with more confidence thanks to the change.

For those of you who say this will reward garbage questions, you have forgotten one thing. It used to be that you would lose reputation for every downvote you cast, but now you can downvote to your heart's content without any penalty!

Comment: I think this is a very valid argument, and as mentioned by the poster, the only one that is apparently from a heavy asker, which is actually the target of the change.  I fail to understand why it attracted any downvotes at all.  On the bright side, with 3 upvotes and 6 downvotes, it would have gained 18 rep points under the new system, even if it was a question :p

Comment: We didn't lose reputation for downvoting questions before, it was only answers. It is still only answers.

Answer (score -11):

Upvoting questions should just not be allowed. The creator of a question should only get reputation from the upvotes of the answers to his/her question. So let's say, for example: each upvote in an answer earns the person who wrote the answer some points and the person who wrote the question earns some other points for each upvote on any answer. This way the experts get rewarded for sharing their knowledge and the ones seeking for knowledge get rewarded for bringing to light problems common to many people.

Answer (score -12):

## This is stupid.

Why do this? And also retroactively?? Plus, people spam the ups but rarely the down votes.
Also, why are downvotes on questions free? Um, wake up! If answer downvotes reduce reputation, questions should too. Some questions deserve to lose dozens of reputation — sometimes more. So why is that free??

Plus, downvotes are already too low. -2 rep?? Are you serious? If anything, **upvotes** should be -4 and downvotes should be +10. Why? People SPAm the upvotes so that it really doesn't matter if it's just +4.

Why wasn't the community consulted? I thought this was a community site!

Comment: Where did you get the -4 from? Isn't it -2?

Comment: *Some questions deserve to lose dozens of reputation — sometimes more.* Yes, asking a terrible question deserves to lose significant reputation.  Casting question downvotes is free so more people will be willing to cast them at all, allowing us to penalize bad questions.  I agree with your conclusion (that this change is not good), but your first paragraph doesn't support this conclusion *at all* and is arguing against itself.

Answer (score -22):

The ultimate goal is that reputation precisely represents contribution, but contribution is very subjective which can never be valued precisely. So discussing what is a better reputation system doesn't have much sense.

The better route is to define some goals that can be measured, like some site statistics, and based on the fixed measurable goals, do experiments and find out which system gauge is better. You can never predict the result before the experiments, like the economy system.

Anyway, Stack Overflow should limit the reputation gain for a single question/answer since that gain is mainly coming from popularity. You can upvote a Q&A for any times, but the reputation gain is only for some limited time.

Stack Overflow can also provide the feature to hide the reputation value. Instead only show some levels like L1/L2.../L9.../L999, like in RPG games, or tags like moderator/new contributor, and then we can focus more on Q&As instead of the annoying +1/-1s. At least give us a personal option to hide reputation and get free.

**Updated**:

Another way to get rid of the noise is that when a user turn on the "no-reputation" feature option, the user can't see the user's own reputation any more and the votes in the user's Q&As is hidden to itself too, but not to other users. Messages about votes/reputations are gone too.

And the name "reputation" is not appropriate either. "Experience points" like in RPG is better.

And base privilege on reputation is not right either. Each privilege should based on its own gauge. All gauges of different privileges are based on a common user activity history database. Then you can change reputation system independent from the privilege system.

Comment: Re *"for any times"*: Do you mean *"many times"*?

Comment: @ Peter Mortensen  No it's any natural number. The meaning is any user can vote a question for 1 time, and the question can be voted up for any times. The votes decide the search result. But the author of the Q/A can't get votes*10 reputation, it's limited to like 5*10 reputation. It's crazy that a simple pupular question get 1000+ votes, the 999 votes come from pupularity, not contribution. I'v seen user with 10K+ reputation only have 3 asked questions. That's the most needed modification since the contribution is just noise in front of pupularity.

Answer (score -28):

Clearly all the promotions this will generate isn't related to the drama with the community? We're having a hard time getting moderation and clearing queues? I mean SE could just hope some more people take on responsibilities for the internet points.

I'd like to think there's some deeper meaning to all of this but I can't imagine that's SE's intent any longer.

Comment: Stack Overflow has always had trouble clearing review queues. The close vote review queue has hovered around 10k questions since it was introduced. It's also worth pointing out that these changes have been planned for *months*, and it's something that some of the CMs and moderators have been thinking about doing for *years*. This isn't a cynical ploy to increase the number of users with moderation privileges. Even if it were, it wouldn't work. Moderating this site is a lot of effort, and it requires *dedicated* users, not just scores on a scoreboard.

Answer (score -31):

Such a giant wall of negativity.

I for one just want to thank the SO team for this change. Good questions are just as valuable as good answers. It was high time that they were valued as such.

Many of the concerns raised are mostly non-issues. You only get access to review queues at 500 rep. That is 50 upvotes without any downvotes. Many people seem to invent doom scenarios over this, but honestly, higher rep only seem to correspond to how jaded people have become (case in point with many of the replies above). The rep gate only exists so people are at least a little bit familiar with the site. People may reach the threshold a little bit earlier, but overall I doubt people that only want to post their homework on Stack Overflow are going to *ruin* Stack Overflow by doing queues that reward no reputation.

Comment: I'd agree with you... if there weren't people who upvote "everything" rather than only upvoting good questions.

Comment: Do you expect 50 of such people driving by on one question? One such person casting 50 votes on 50 questions? Trash questions rarely get a score above 0 and on average should still get a negative score, which means someone needs to post at least 63 questions to get 500 rep with 0-score on all of their questions. I hope that the system would severely limit that person at that point. If it doesn't, the 167 questions someone needed to ask before is not going to change anything either. Both amounts are huge, even if you just put your homework here.

Comment: The problem I see is not people getting access to tools they're not ready for (that might also be a problem, but I'd consider it secondary at best), but that the number of help vampires and the amount of homework questions wil increase even more. This is a downward spiral that (at least in my experience) leads to knowledgeable people losing interest and leaving, which in turn leads to overall decreased quality of the content, which in turn leads to less people coming to the site. I've seen this happen in other communities before.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Who would complain about more reputation points? But then there is rep envy.

Comment: The negativity is not for increasing the rep on questions, it is for not increasing the penalty for down votes. In fact, more stringent policies are required to stop bad quality questions and make SO a great place again. How many times would you like to read and answer to someone asking about the best library to solve X, for example?

Comment: Thanks, I totally agree with you.