# How will the retroactive question reputation changes manifest on my SO account?

Tags: discussion, reputation, reputation-history

I flipped through the answers and comments on the thread about [retroactively rewarding questions with more reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391250/upvotes-on-questions-will-now-be-worth-the-same-as-upvotes-on-answers?cb=1) and I did not see my specific question answered.

When the retroactive reputation application hits, *how* will I see this manifest in my SE accounts?

I have already received a number of new "Yearling" badges. Will I also see the upvote rep changes come in as individual line items? Will I just see my total rep jump?

I want to note that I want to focus this question and answers on the mechanics of the change and *not* the politics of the change. When and how will the numbers move?

Comment: Your SO rep suddenly jumped up by ~730 points.  You were not close to any new badges or privileges and there's no notification for the increase beyond the blog post.   So that's all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391250/upvotes-on-questions-will-now-be-worth-the-same-as-upvotes-on-answers

Comment: You won’t get any notification at all. The rep will just jump when the recalculation on the database is complete for your account. History will be completely rewritten (“we’ve always been at war with Eastasia”); you won’t even be able to see what your old rep level was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no special notification.
The only way for you to see the difference is to check your reputation log.
For example you retroactively got +10 rep for the upvote on Nov 11 to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16671706/how-can-i-tell-intellijs-find-in-files-to-ignore-generated-files) question.