# Is there a way to know my "total" reputation before "Rewarding the Question Askers" change was applied?

Tags: support, reputation, upvotes, reputation-history

I read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/391250/5779732) SO Meta post and [this](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/?cb=1) blog post today.

I do not monitor my reputation so closely. I do not remember what was my reputation yesterday before "Rewarding the Question Askers" change was applied.

I guess it was around 8700 something; do not remember the exact number.

If I roughly calculate with my total question up-votes (76 so far), I should gain 380 points. Today's reputation is 8895.

I checked the reputation tab and [reputation log](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) and confirmed that question up vote is awarded 10 points instead of 5 as expected.

Just to confirm, is there a way to know my **total** reputation before "Rewarding the Question Askers" change was applied?

Comment: Moderators can see this information in a history log, but I don’t think there’s any way that a user can see this about themselves. You previously had 8485 reputation; your recalculated rep was 8895.

Comment: @wha That’s an estimation, but not precisely correct. It fails to take into account the daily reputation limit, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented by @CodyGray in [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391333/is-there-a-way-to-know-my-total-reputation-before-rewarding-the-question-aske?noredirect=1#comment740371_391333) comment, I get my answer.

> Moderators can see this information in a history log, but I don’t think there’s any way that a user can see this about themselves. **You previously had 8485 reputation; your recalculated rep was 8895**. – Cody Gray♦

Thanks @CodyGray.