# Was it a coincidence or was my bounty refunded?

Tags: support, reputation, bounty

I created a bounty on one of my question, but there were no answers and I found out the solution on 3rd day and posted it and there was no other answer for the duration of the bounty, however after 7 days I got upvotes giving me reputation exactly equal to the amount of my wasted bounty. Is this just a coincidence?

[image: Reputation log]

Comment: It wasn't refunded (no refunds!). You earned more reputation of equal amount.

Comment: It's pretty usual that a small bounty gets you a lot of upvotes due to the extra attention. There has actually been discussion about users starting a bounty on questions they have an answer to with the goal to draw attention to it and earn more rep than they lose (can't find it atm), which is allowed afaik. With 10 rep on votes on questions, it's now even easier to break even or gain than it was before.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense but gaining upvotes exactly after 7 days (on bounty expiration day) had me confused...

Comment: Bounties that are about to expire get more views than bounties that have just been opened.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Just an asterisk to your comment: moderators can refund bounty rep when canceling one, though it is a rare occurrence (canceling a bounty is rare, refunding rep for a canceled bounty is even rarer).

Comment: Hi folks! The answer box is down yonder way ↓

Comment: Since you found the answer, please take the time to write a clear answer even though it's your own question. That'll help others in the future, and you might earn upvotes (and more rep) on both your question and your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was essentially a coincidence. You gave away 100 reputation for the bounty, and then you got 10 upvotes, each worth +10 reputation apiece. Thus, the upvotes neatly canceled out the reputation that you lost from the bounty.

I say "essentially" because it wasn't *entirely* a coincidence. You see, when you set a bounty on a question, it puts that question into the "featured" tab on the Stack Overflow homepage, thus attracting additional attention to that question. Some of the viewers of your question are naturally going to upvote it (assuming, of course, that it's a well-asked question). As the bounty gets closer to expiring, your question gets moved closer to the top of the "featured" list, thus resulting in even more views.

The reason you're getting +10 reputation for each upvote on your question is because of [a recent change making question upvotes equal to answer upvotes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391250/upvotes-on-questions-will-now-be-worth-the-same-as-upvotes-on-answers).

Your bounty was not refunded. Bounties are almost never refunded, even if you don't get an answer to your question. What you're paying for with the bounty is the *increased exposure* of your question, so even if you don't get an answer, you've still gotten the benefit of the bounty.

The only way a bounty can be refunded is by getting a diamond moderator involved, and we'll only cancel bounties under exceptional circumstances. That didn't happen here.

Comment: A perfect use case of what I said about the new Rep change: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/391307/8620333. I guess we can even earn more Rep using bounty now.

Comment: @Temani Yes, with the caveat that featuring may also attract downvotes on low-quality questions.