# After rewarding the question askers, were the privileges granted accordingly?

Tags: support, notifications, privileges

After [rewarding the question askers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/), were the privileges granted accordingly?

After the adjustment, my reputation crossed 2K. But the [edit questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) privilege was granted to me today after an upvote on one of my answers. Or processing of granting the privilege and an upvote on one of my answers is just a coincidence?

Comment: Well, it does make sense to only recalculate privileges when an upvote arrives ... (in case no one is manipulating the calculation afterwards)

Answer (score 2):

The privileges were granted when the reputation recalculation completed. When [the worth of question upvotes was doubled](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391250/upvotes-on-questions-will-now-be-worth-the-same-as-upvotes-on-answers), your reputation went from 1969 to 2254. So, yes, you immediately gained the privilege to [edit questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) without community review. Privileges are gained (or lost, as the case may be) the moment you pass the reputation threshold.

However, you don't necessarily receive a *notification* that you've earned the privilege. Recalculations do not trigger notifications. You will only see the notification when a new event occurs that causes your reputation to increase—in this case, it was the upvote you received on one of your answers.

Comment: Interesting! Any pointers to read in-depth about the services architectures of stackoverflow?