# Question vs Answer Reputation Points

Tags: discussion, reputation, upvotes

Is it fair to have the **same** reputation points on the *upvotes* for a question and an answer, I find it very unfair to have the same amount of points, Because when you ask a question you get both [answer + reputation point] in return, while when you answer you only get reputation.

I think the system should change and the answer *upvote* should get double the amount.

There is another disadvantage of this that users will start asking questions to get reputations rather than getting answers

Comment: It used to be like that and was changed. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391250/upvotes-on-questions-will-now-be-worth-the-same-as-upvotes-on-answers

Comment: All upvotes are worth ten XP. However, XP [aka reputation] gained from upvotes are capped at 200 daily.

Comment: @Ḿűỻịgǻṇącểơửṩᛗ "XP" is a very weird abbreviation for "reputation"...

Comment: @CodyGray SE reputation is comparable to XP anyhow.

Comment: Well, [it's better than Vista](https://xkcd.com/528/). @Ḿűỻịgǻṇącểơửṩᛗ

Comment: I got (Windows) *10* (Windows) *XP* while contributing in StackOverflow.

Comment: "*when you ask a question you
get both [answer + reputation point] in return, while when you answer you only get reputation*" if you write a **good question** (one worth upvotes), then it's not only *the asker* who benefits but anybody else who comes to the question. So, were we to follow the logic of "upvote = benefit" to determine the rep, then an upvote to a question should be worth *more*. People come to here from search engines for the *questions*, not the answers.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it fair

Depends on your point of view. Lots of things in life are fair for some individual, some not.

> to have the same reputation points on the up votes for a question and an answer.

Depends on what you optimize for. If the game designer feels a good answer needs to be rewarded more then a question they turn on the reputation knobs. That line of reasoning prevailed until a few months ago. Based on feedback SE got they considered that asking a good question is also hard so that needs to be rewarded. An side-effect of this is might be that more questions get asked and that means content, and that means imprints and that means money for the Venture Capitalists.

> I find it very unfair to have the same amount of points, Because when you ask a question you get both [answer + reputation point] in return, while when you answer you only get reputation.

I only follow that reasoning up to some point. Writing an answer that gets accepted earns you the most, so users can still game for that. Also [answers get way more up votes, historically, then questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/813466/up-accept-and-down-votes-over-time#graph). The game designer has some point that they prefer to level the playing field a bit for the group of users that is more into asking then into answering.

> I think the system should change and the answer upvote should get double the amount.

I think it is too early to call. The system needs to run for a while until the game designers can notice a statistically significant change to base future decisions on.

> There is another disadvantage of this that users will start asking questions to get reputations rather than getting answers

Yes, but this is in the interest of getting more content overall (as these questions also need answers) and it is believed that the SO Inc. aims at earning some money from running  ads next to content. The content matters, the quality of it not so much anymore.

Comment: Gotta disagree with a lot of this. Getting more content was never presented as a justification for the change in scoring. Also, this isn't a game. We don't have anything nearly as well thought out as "designers" for this universe.

Comment: @CodyGray I have the gut feeling that lately things are presented differently by some parties so we can spin any justification. While you're free to not see it as a "game" the whole concept is based on Gamification, so there is a kind of game play at work here and that needs "design" ...  ;)